# How to get IP address of the device from code?

Tags: android, ip-address

Is it possible to get the IP address of the device using some code?

Comment: Don't forget that this is a collection of size N, and you can't assume that N == ( 0 || 1 ).  In other words, don't assume that a device only has one way of talking to a network and don't assume that it has any way to talk to a network at all.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-current-machine-using-java

Comment: non programmatic version http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/how-can-i-see-what-ip-address-my-android-phone-has

Comment: You should get it from an external service http://ipof.in/txt is one such service

Comment: is it possible to get it programatically in android?

Comment: See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730711/get-my-wifi-ip-address-android/50871614#50871614

Answer (score 239, accepted):

With permission `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

One can use the `WifiManager` to obtain the IP address:

```
Context context = requireContext().getApplicationContext();
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Comment: Great solution! Work well with Android 3.0 when using-NetworkInterface-solution return something like MAC Address

Comment: Why did you use List<WifiConfiguration> and wc here? :s

Comment: this one works for me . however , it needs "ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" permission and as "Umair" wrote , the list usage is not needed.

Comment: formatIpAddress is deprecated for some reason. What should be used instead?

Comment: From the docs: Use `getHostAddress()`, which supports both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. This method does not support IPv6 addresses.

Comment: how to use getHostAddress() in getting the server & client ip address @RyanR ?

Comment: I am using same code within fragment but I am getting WIFI_Service not found cannot resolve

Comment: will this still work even if the user uses data instead of wifi?

Comment: does this work even if I am connected to LAN and not to wifi?

Comment: Android Studio now displays a warning, do `getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE)`

Comment: Nah this not answering directly to OP. Because not all Android devices using WiFi to connect to internet. It might have NATed LAN on Ethernet, or BT and not NATed WAN connection etc.

Comment: This only works for Wifi interface I think. It won't get the correct IP if the phone is connected via an eth cable or for other interfaces (VPN tunnels for instance)

Comment: @DivyanshuKushwaha Isn't there a more official way?

Comment: it returns wifi device ip

Comment: it return 0.0.0.0 when I switch to using data instead of wifi connection

Comment: Kotlin <br/>fun getdeviceIpAddress_Wifi(): String? {
        val context: Context = this.applicationContext
        val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(ComponentActivity.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        val ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifiManager.connectionInfo.ipAddress)
        return ip;
    } // import      t
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager
import android.text.format.Formatter

import java.net.Inet4Address
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.NetworkInterface
import java.net.SocketException
import java.util.*

Comment: This method was deprecated in API version 12 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846120/alternative-for-formatter-formatipaddressint/26915348

Answer (score 491):

This is my helper util to read IP and MAC addresses. Implementation is pure-java, but I have a comment block in `getMACAddress()` which could read the value from the special Linux(Android) file. I've run this code only on few devices and Emulator but let me know here if you find weird results.

```
// AndroidManifest.xml permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

// test functions
Utils.getMACAddress("wlan0");
Utils.getMACAddress("eth0");
Utils.getIPAddress(true); // IPv4
Utils.getIPAddress(false); // IPv6
```

**Utils.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;   
//import org.apache.http.conn.util.InetAddressUtils;

public class Utils {

    /**
     * Convert byte array to hex string
     * @param bytes toConvert
     * @return hexValue
     */
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
        for(int idx=0; idx < bytes.length; idx++) {
            int intVal = bytes[idx] & 0xff;
            if (intVal < 0x10) sbuf.append("0");
            sbuf.append(Integer.toHexString(intVal).toUpperCase());
        }
        return sbuf.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Get utf8 byte array.
     * @param str which to be converted
     * @return  array of NULL if error was found
     */
    public static byte[] getUTF8Bytes(String str) {
        try { return str.getBytes("UTF-8"); } catch (Exception ex) { return null; }
    }

    /**
     * Load UTF8withBOM or any ansi text file.
     * @param filename which to be converted to string
     * @return String value of File
     * @throws java.io.IOException if error occurs
     */
    public static String loadFileAsString(String filename) throws java.io.IOException {
        final int BUFLEN=1024;
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename), BUFLEN);
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(BUFLEN);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFLEN];
            boolean isUTF8=false;
            int read,count=0;           
            while((read=is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                if (count==0 && bytes[0]==(byte)0xEF && bytes[1]==(byte)0xBB && bytes[2]==(byte)0xBF ) {
                    isUTF8=true;
                    baos.write(bytes, 3, read-3); // drop UTF8 bom marker
                } else {
                    baos.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }
                count+=read;
            }
            return isUTF8 ? new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8") : new String(baos.toByteArray());
        } finally {
            try{ is.close(); } catch(Exception ignored){} 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns MAC address of the given interface name.
     * @param interfaceName eth0, wlan0 or NULL=use first interface 
     * @return  mac address or empty string
     */
    public static String getMACAddress(String interfaceName) {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
                if (interfaceName != null) {
                    if (!intf.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(interfaceName)) continue;
                }
                byte[] mac = intf.getHardwareAddress();
                if (mac==null) return "";
                StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte aMac : mac) buf.append(String.format("%02X:",aMac));  
                if (buf.length()>0) buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length()-1);
                return buf.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) { } // for now eat exceptions
        return "";
        /*try {
            // this is so Linux hack
            return loadFileAsString("/sys/class/net/" +interfaceName + "/address").toUpperCase().trim();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return null;
        }*/
    }

    /**
     * Get IP address from first non-localhost interface
     * @param useIPv4   true=return ipv4, false=return ipv6
     * @return  address or empty string
     */
    public static String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4) {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
                List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
                for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                    if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
                        //boolean isIPv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr);
                        boolean isIPv4 = sAddr.indexOf(':')<0;

                        if (useIPv4) {
                            if (isIPv4) 
                                return sAddr;
                        } else {
                            if (!isIPv4) {
                                int delim = sAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 zone suffix
                                return delim<0 ? sAddr.toUpperCase() : sAddr.substring(0, delim).toUpperCase();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) { } // for now eat exceptions
        return "";
    }

}
```

> Disclaimer: Ideas and example code to this Utils class came from
>   several SO posts and Google. I have cleaned and merged all examples.

Comment: This requires API level 9 and above because of getHardwareAddress().

Comment: Problems - lint warnings on `toUpperCase()`. Catching `Exception` is always dodgy (and helper methods should throw anyway and let the caller deal with the Exception - did not amend this though). Formatting : should be no more than 80 lines. Conditional execution for `getHardwareAddress()` - patch : https://github.com/Utumno/AndroidHelpers/commit/b285df75ab6dd1e724e1985d480d18be3a8692a7. What you say ?

Comment: If you are on a local network (e.g. Wifi or emulator), you will get a private IP address. You can get the proxy IP address through a request to a specific website which gives you the proxy address, e.g. http://whatismyip.akamai.com/

Comment: Get very strange IP address in Genymotion/in virtual box emulator: 10.0.3.15 . Pinging does not work because the IP is invalid?

Comment: Erwinus: Both the 10.x.x.x and 192.168.x.x are private IPs. Relates to virtual box guestOS network routing. I know nothing about Genymotion but I guess there is options to open(port forward) private ips to hostOS.

Comment: Why do you need the `toUpperCase()`?

Comment: kilaka: toUpperCase is to force IP6 address to uppercase. You can leave it out if want use any case device platform is returning.

Comment: In which cases should we use the IP6 format? is it useful for WIFI network (LAN ) ?

Comment: Hi,I get the default gateway instead of IP address . :(

Comment: This doesnt work for me in Android 4.4 emulator. Is this code need real device

Comment: This works perfect for me with real device using Wifi. Thanks a lot, bro

Comment: @Holame: thx for notifying sdk change, I have modified an example code not to use an obsolete helper class. It should work for old and new sdk profiles.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Does anyone know if the Android 6 changes affect this approach?  See this link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

Comment: I'm getting bad results from this on a Nexus 6 when trying to get an IP address. I have a NetworkInterface with name "name:dummy0 (dummy0)" that gives an address with the format "/XX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%dummy0", there is also a real network interface that corresponds to wlan0, but since the "dummy" happens first I always get that dummy address

Comment: works great.. thanks. I would +2 if I could for handling ethernet connections, and not just wifi.

Comment: @Seth You could merge getMACAddress+getIPAddress functions to have that feature. Loop for interface objects by given name (eth0 or similar, debug.print all names first), read IP address from that interface object.

Comment: Works, thanks, there are various other posts, some are short, depend on WifiManager but they fail to get the ip of the phone carrier, they only get the one of the local wifi network.

Comment: I love how this is pure JVM based

Comment: But it returns the first address it finds, for ipv4 it's fine since there is only one, but for ipv6 based addresses there are more than one, so how do i make sure that the first address it returns is the correct ipv6 address

Comment: Probably will be good to add !inetAddress.isLinkLocalAddress()  check on if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress())  to prevent getting ipv6 link local addresses.

Comment: Keep in that some devices (such as nexus 5x) return the cellular ip first using this way and you are maybe interested in the local/wifi ip...

Comment: If you look at this and think it's way too complicated, I posted an answer that simplifies it and adds some explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51311401/4714742

Comment: @Whome Utils.getMACAddress("wlan0"); Utils.getMACAddress("eth0"); both return null when called from mobile which is connected to the internet using 4G mobile data, any other method to get ip in such case ?

Comment: @pcj try calling `getMACAddress(null)` and see what's returned. Debug print all interface names to see what your device is using. Modify that same method to print out to a logcat.

Comment: @Whome I edited to return any available interface to which has mac address, Then for "ccmni4" type of interface I got ip also mac is different based on interface we send as argument this must be behaviour of mac, on one perticular Android device we get changed mac after some time, Can mac address gets changed after some time for the same interface ?

Comment: @pcj I have seen chinese Android media sticks devices to change MAC on every reboot. Anything is possible I guess.

Comment: :) Concluded that mac cannot be used to identify a device ( As it may change ), Thanks for help @Whome!!!

Comment: Thanks,But does this still works for new versions of android?  Utils.getMACAddress("wlan0");
Utils.getMACAddress("eth0");
Utils.getIPAddress(true);

Comment: @CWilliams Some devices have a "random" interface name so wlan0,eth0 may not give anything. `getMACAddress(null)` is using the first interface found. You may need to printout all interface names to see your device naming.

Comment: @zeleven Most likely your device is using the different network interface names, try `getMACAddress(null)` to use first interface. Also print out all available interface names. Or do you mean `getIPAddress(true)` IP getter is empty?

Comment: @Whome Yes, I got nothing when I call the `getIPAddress(true)` method, the return value always empty.

Comment: @zeleven strange if no ipv4 addr available and `getIPAddress(false)` to get ipv6 also empty? Then I don't know what is, you should print out an exception if that is to happen, example function silently eats EX. Final reason is to have only a localhost interface, I guess you need to add logcat debug calls to a getter function.

Comment: @Whome Above method for ipv4 gives different result than what is my IP in google. Above nethod give me IP address of UK and what is my IP in google gives me IP address of India that is correct. Any idea or anyone face this problem ?

Comment: @Smeet most likely your device has a private and public IP infrastructure(NAT, company routing gateway etc.). This method does not see what happens in a routing/NAT etc side. Or your device has multiple IPs.

Answer (score 90):

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've added `inetAddress` instanceof `Inet4Address` to check if it is a ipv4 address.

Comment: There's no way to get the public IP other than to hit some external REST endpoint that reports back what it sees as the public IP, for example: https://api.ipify.org/?format=json. The device doesn't even know the public IP address itself.

Answer (score 67):

I used following code:
The reason I used hashCode was because I was getting some garbage values appended to the ip address when I used `getHostAddress` . But `hashCode` worked really well for me as then I can use Formatter to get the ip address with correct formatting.

Here is the example output :

1.using `getHostAddress` : `***** IP=fe80::65ca:a13d:ea5a:233d%rmnet_sdio0`

2.using `hashCode` and `Formatter` :  `***** IP=238.194.77.212`

As you can see 2nd methods gives me exactly what I need.

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());
                    Log.i(TAG, "***** IP="+ ip);
                    return ip;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `getHostAddress()` will do the same as the formatter stuff you added.

Comment: Using hashCode is plain wrong, and returns nonsense. Use InetAddress.getHostAddress() instead.

Comment: change this part:

if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String ip =     Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());
                    Log.i(TAG, "***** IP="+ ip);
                    return ip;
 }

with this:
if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() &&  InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(inetAddress.getHostAddress())) {
             return inetAddress .getHostAddress().toString();
}

this will give you the correct ip format

Comment: The code only return first IP, a phone may have celluar, WIFI and BT address at same time

Comment: @Chuy47 it says InetAddressUtils cannot be found

Comment: @FabioR it seems that the InetAddressUtils class is now gone but you can use "inetAddress.getHostAddress() instanceof Inet4Address" instead of "InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(inetAddress.getHostAddress())". 

More info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141785/android-api-23-inetaddressutils-replacement

Comment: @Chuy47 thank you for such quick reply!
It works, however, it gets my network IP and I'd need the public one, any idea of how to do it?

Comment: @FabioR, sorry, I just saw this last question, maybe this answer can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308000/determine-device-public-ip

Comment: @Chuy47 np, thanks for answering!
Indeed, I ended up using that same approach, checking my public IP in an API (I used the ipify one), it worked!

Answer (score 62):

Though there's a correct answer, I share my answer here and hope that this way will more convenience.

```
WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
int ipAddress = wifiInf.getIpAddress();
String ip = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
```

Comment: Thanks! Formatter is deprecated, and I really didn't feel like writing simple bit logic.

Comment: Works great, but requires WIFI_STATE permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />`

Comment: I use the formaater but it doesnt work. It is great! Really appreciated. Could you explain what is done in last line. I know %d.%d.%d.%d however others ? Thanks

Comment: Nah this not answering directly to OP. Because not all Android devices using WiFi to connect to internet. It might have NATed LAN on Ethernet, or BT and not NATed WAN connection etc.

Answer (score 34):

Below code might help you.. Don't forget to add permissions..

```
public String getLocalIpAddress(){
   try {
       for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();  
       en.hasMoreElements();) {
       NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
           for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
           InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
           }
       }
       } catch (Exception ex) {
          Log.e("IP Address", ex.toString());
      }
      return null;
}
```

Add below permission in the manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

happy coding!!

Comment: Hey this returns an incorrect value  like : "fe80::f225:b7ff:fe8c:d357%wlan0"

Comment: @Jorgesys check for evertvandenbruel's answer where he added inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address

Comment: change if condition like this to get correct ip:if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address)

Comment: The code only return first IP, a phone may have celluar, WIFI and BT address at same time

Comment: If you have a hotspot on, you may get more than one ip

Answer (score 30):

kotlin minimalist version

```
fun getIpv4HostAddress(): String {
    NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()?.toList()?.map { networkInterface ->
        networkInterface.inetAddresses?.toList()?.find {
            !it.isLoopbackAddress && it is Inet4Address
        }?.let { return it.hostAddress }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You do not need to add permissions like what is the case with the solutions provided so far. Download this website as a string:

http://www.ip-api.com/json

or

http://www.telize.com/geoip

Downloading a website as a string can be done with java code:

http://www.itcuties.com/java/read-url-to-string/

Parse the JSON object like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998203/1987258

The json attribute "query" or "ip" contains the IP address.

Comment: this needs Internet Connection. Big problem

Comment: Why is that a big problem? Of course you need an internet connection because an IP address is technically related to such a connecetion. If you leave your house and go to a restaurant you will use another internet connection and thus another IP address. You do not need something to add more like  ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE or ACCESS_WIFI_STATE. An internet connection is the only permission you need for the solution provided by me.

Comment: this not guaranties your app get IP. because there is no  guarantee for that domain remain online.

Comment: Which domain? If ip-api.com does not work, you can use telize.com as a fallback.  Otherwise you can use https://api.ipify.org/ . It is also available here (not json): http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=showIP .  Many apps use domains that are to guaranteed to remain online; that is normal. However, if you use fallbacks then it becomes highly unlikely that there will be a problem.

Comment: David's original point still stands. What if you're on an internal network which doesn't have access to internet.

Comment: I never thought about that because I do not know any practical purpose of an app that definitely needs a network but should work without internet (maybe there is but I don't see it for mobile devices).

Comment: As someone who is currently developing an enterprise app which is not legally allowed to have an internet connection, David's point represents me.

Comment: Also note that using this method you will get the external IP that the API service sees and not the actual device IP. The device could be on a local network using a private IP and this happens in most WIFI connections so definitely won't be reliable at all.

Comment: NOT WORKING Free, They provide "http" for free, "https" for paid. If you use this free API in Volley for get Json data, It will be redirected to "https" that showing Error because for "https" you need their premium.

Answer (score 10):

```
private InetAddress getLocalAddress()throws IOException {

            try {
                for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                        if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                            //return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                            return inetAddress;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Log.e("SALMAN", ex.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: is it possible that this would return the private network ip from the wifi interface, like 192.168.0.x? or will it always return the external ip address, that would be used on the internet?

Answer (score 9):

Method getDeviceIpAddress returns device's ip address and prefers wifi interface address if it connected.

```
  @NonNull
    private String getDeviceIpAddress() {
        String actualConnectedToNetwork = null;
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
                actualConnectedToNetwork = getWifiIp();
            }
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(actualConnectedToNetwork)) {
            actualConnectedToNetwork = getNetworkInterfaceIpAddress();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(actualConnectedToNetwork)) {
            actualConnectedToNetwork = "127.0.0.1";
        }
        return actualConnectedToNetwork;
    }

    @Nullable
    private String getWifiIp() {
        final WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (mWifiManager != null && mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            int ip = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
            return (ip & 0xFF) + "." + ((ip >> 8) & 0xFF) + "." + ((ip >> 16) & 0xFF) + "."
                    + ((ip >> 24) & 0xFF);
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Nullable
    public String getNetworkInterfaceIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = networkInterface.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        String host = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(host)) {
                            return host;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("IP Address", "getLocalIpAddress", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [LinkProperties](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LinkProperties). It's recommended for new Android versions.

This function retrieves local IP address for both WiFi and Mobile Data. It requires `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission.

```
@Nullable
public static String getDeviceIpAddress(@NonNull ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {
    LinkProperties linkProperties = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
    InetAddress inetAddress;
    for(LinkAddress linkAddress : linkProperties.getLinkAddresses()) {
        inetAddress = linkAddress.getAddress();
        if (inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address
                && !inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()
                && inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
            return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: "new Android versions" means >= api 21 (android 5, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getLinkProperties(android.net.Network)). This is also the preferred way if you want to receive ip address of specific Network (just pass it as parameter to getLinkProperties).

Answer (score 6):

In your activity, the following function `getIpAddress(context)` returns the phone's IP address:

```
public static String getIpAddress(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

    String ipAddress = intToInetAddress(wifiManager.getDhcpInfo().ipAddress).toString();

    ipAddress = ipAddress.substring(1);

    return ipAddress;
}

public static InetAddress intToInetAddress(int hostAddress) {
    byte[] addressBytes = { (byte)(0xff & hostAddress),
                (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 8)),
                (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 16)),
                (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 24)) };

    try {
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(addressBytes);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting 0.0.0.0

Comment: Is your phone connected to a wifi network ? Which value is returned if you call wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID() ?

Comment: Will it work for device connected to Mobile Data, not WiFi?

Comment: No, this method works only if device is connected to WiFi

Answer (score 5):

This is a rework of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13007325/4714742) which strips out irrelevant information, adds helpful comments, names variables more clearly, and improves the logic.

Don't forget to include the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

InternetHelper.java:

```
public class InternetHelper {

    /**
     * Get IP address from first non-localhost interface
     *
     * @param useIPv4 true=return ipv4, false=return ipv6
     * @return address or empty string
     */
    public static String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4) {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces =
                    Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());

            for (NetworkInterface interface_ : interfaces) {

                for (InetAddress inetAddress :
                        Collections.list(interface_.getInetAddresses())) {

                    /* a loopback address would be something like 127.0.0.1 (the device
                       itself). we want to return the first non-loopback address. */
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        String ipAddr = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                        boolean isIPv4 = ipAddr.indexOf(':') < 0;

                        if (isIPv4 && !useIPv4) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (useIPv4 && !isIPv4) {
                            int delim = ipAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 zone suffix
                            ipAddr = delim < 0 ? ipAddr.toUpperCase() :
                                    ipAddr.substring(0, delim).toUpperCase();
                        }
                        return ipAddr;
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) { } // if we can't connect, just return empty string
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Get IPv4 address from first non-localhost interface
     *
     * @return address or empty string
     */
    public static String getIPAddress() {
        return getIPAddress(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static String getdeviceIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This code helped me get the local IP address of the Hotspot. 192.168.55.66 in my case . Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ipAddress = BigInteger.valueOf(wm.getDhcpInfo().netmask).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently, an IP address is still returned by `getLocalIpAddress()` despite being disconnected from the network (no service indicator). It means the IP address displayed in the Settings> About phone> Status was different from what the application thought.

I have implemented a workaround by adding this code before:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = getConnectivityManager();
NetworkInfo net = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if ((null == net) || !net.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    return null;
}
```

Does that ring a bell to anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use Volley to get the ip from [this](http://checkip.amazonaws.com/) site

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);    
String urlip = "http://checkip.amazonaws.com/";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlip, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            txtIP.setText(response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            txtIP.setText("didnt work");
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: this is to fetch a public ip, and is dependant on amazon's aws check ip service which might eventually change or disappear one day, and only works if the device has access to internet. on a local network, or when offline, it will not work. furthermore, notice that the checkip service is not secure, and can therefore be faked by a man in the middle. to get the list of IP addresses of a device, we need to query the list of network interfaces of the device(cellular, wifi, etc...), and get the addresses which are not local.

Answer (score 2):

in Kotlin, without Formatter

```
private fun getIPAddress(useIPv4 : Boolean): String {
    try {
        var interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())
        for (intf in interfaces) {
            var addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (addr in addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    var sAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
                    var isIPv4: Boolean
                    isIPv4 = sAddr.indexOf(':')<0
                    if (useIPv4) {
                        if (isIPv4)
                            return sAddr;
                    } else {
                        if (!isIPv4) {
                            var delim = sAddr.indexOf('%') // drop ip6 zone suffix
                            if (delim < 0) {
                                return sAddr.toUpperCase()
                            }
                            else {
                                return sAddr.substring(0, delim).toUpperCase()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) { }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A device might have several IP addresses, and the one in use in a particular app might not be the IP that servers receiving the request will see. Indeed, some users use a VPN or a proxy such as [Cloudflare Warp](https://blog.cloudflare.com/1111-warp-better-vpn/).

If your purpose is to get the IP address as shown by servers that receive requests from your device, then the best is to query an IP geolocation service such as [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co) (disclaimer: I work for the company) with its Java client:

https://github.com/ipregistry/ipregistry-java

```
IpregistryClient client = new IpregistryClient("tryout");
RequesterIpInfo requesterIpInfo = client.lookup();
requesterIpInfo.getIp();
```

In addition to being really simple to use, you get additional information such as country, language, currency, the time zone for the device IP and you can identify whether the user is using a proxy.

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest and simple way ever exist on the internet...
First of all, add this permission to your manifest file...

1. "INTERNET"
2. "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

add this in onCreate file of Activity..

> ```
>     getPublicIP();
> ```

Now Add this function to your MainActivity.class.

```js
    private void getPublicIP() {
ArrayList<String> urls=new ArrayList<String>(); //to read each line

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //TextView t; //to show the result, please declare and find it inside onCreate()

                try {
                    // Create a URL for the desired page
                    URL url = new URL("https://api.ipify.org/"); //My text file location
                    //First open the connection
                    HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(60000); // timing out in a minute

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                    //t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1); // ideally do this in onCreate()
                    String str;
                    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        urls.add(str);
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("MyTag",e.toString());
                }

                //since we are in background thread, to post results we have to go back to ui thread. do the following for that

                PermissionsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(PermissionsActivity.this, "Public IP:"+urls.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(PermissionsActivity.this, "TurnOn wiffi to get public ip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();

    }
```

Comment: urls.get(0)   contains your public IP adress.

Comment: You must declare in your activity file like this:     ArrayList<String> urls=new ArrayList<String>(); //to read each line

Comment: Doesn't work when connected with the phone internet. How to get Public ip in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Here is kotlin version of @Nilesh and @anargund

```
  fun getIpAddress(): String {
    var ip = ""
    try {
        val wm = applicationContext.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.connectionInfo.ipAddress)
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {

    }

    if (ip.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            val en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
            while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
                val networkInterface = en.nextElement()
                val enumIpAddr = networkInterface.inetAddresses
                while (enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements()) {
                    val inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement()
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress && inetAddress is Inet4Address) {
                        val host = inetAddress.getHostAddress()
                        if (host.isNotEmpty()) {
                            ip =  host
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {

        }
    }

   if (ip.isEmpty())
      ip = "127.0.0.1"
    return ip
}
```

Comment: If this is your code style in real projects, I suggest you read "clean code" by robert martin

Answer (score 1):

Compiling some of the ideas to get the wifi ip from the `WifiManager` in a nicer kotlin solution:

```
private fun getWifiIp(context: Context): String? {
  return context.getSystemService<WifiManager>().let {
     when {
      it == null -> "No wifi available"
      !it.isWifiEnabled -> "Wifi is disabled"
      it.connectionInfo == null -> "Wifi not connected"
      else -> {
        val ip = it.connectionInfo.ipAddress
        ((ip and 0xFF).toString() + "." + (ip shr 8 and 0xFF) + "." + (ip shr 16 and 0xFF) + "." + (ip shr 24 and 0xFF))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can get the ip adresses of ip4 loopback devices via the `NetworkInterface`:

```
fun getNetworkIp4LoopbackIps(): Map<String, String> = try {
  NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
    .asSequence()
    .associate { it.displayName to it.ip4LoopbackIps() }
    .filterValues { it.isNotEmpty() }
} catch (ex: Exception) {
  emptyMap()
}

private fun NetworkInterface.ip4LoopbackIps() =
  inetAddresses.asSequence()
    .filter { !it.isLoopbackAddress && it is Inet4Address }
    .map { it.hostAddress }
    .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
    .joinToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote
> // get Device Ip Address

```
open fun getLocalIpAddress(): String? {
    try {
        val en: Enumeration<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            val networkInterface: NetworkInterface = en.nextElement()
            val enumerationIpAddress: Enumeration<InetAddress> = networkInterface.inetAddresses
            while (enumerationIpAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                val inetAddress: InetAddress = enumerationIpAddress.nextElement()
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress && inetAddress is Inet4Address) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress()
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ex: SocketException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shell ; ifconfig eth0 worked for x86 device too

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code...Using this code. we will get ip from mobile internet...

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't do Android, but I'd tackle this in a totally different way.

Send a query to Google, something like:
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=my%20ip

And refer to the HTML field where the response is posted. You may also query directly to the source.

Google will most like be there for longer than your Application.

Just remember, it could be that your user does not have internet at this time, what would you like to happen !

Good Luck

Comment: Interesting!  And I bet that Google has some sort of API call that will return your IP, which will be more stable than scanning HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
String stringUrl = "https://ipinfo.io/ip";
//String stringUrl = "http://whatismyip.akamai.com/";
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.instance);
//String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, stringUrl,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                Log.e(MGLogTag, "GET IP : " + response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        IP = "That didn't work!";
    }
});

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //    @NonNull
    public static String getIPAddress() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(deviceIpAddress))
            new PublicIPAddress().execute();
        return deviceIpAddress;
    }

    public static String deviceIpAddress = "";

    public static class PublicIPAddress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        InetAddress localhost = null;

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                URL url_name = new URL("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com");
                BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url_name.openStream()));
                deviceIpAddress = sc.readLine().trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                deviceIpAddress = "";
            }
            return deviceIpAddress;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
            Lg.d("deviceIpAddress", string);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty I am only a little familiar with code safety, so this may be hack-ish. But for me this is the most versatile way to do it:

```
package com.my_objects.ip;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MyIpByHost 
{
  public static void main(String a[])
  {
   try 
    {
      InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("nameOfDevice or webAddress");
      System.out.println(host.getHostAddress());
    } 
   catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
} }
```

Comment: Would InetAddress return IP of the device that the current device is connected to instead of the IP of the current device?

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin language.

```
fun contextIP(context: Context): String {
    val wm: WifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    return Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.connectionInfo.ipAddress)
}
```

Comment: Deprecated method

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way of finding device ip address.

```
package com.oseamiya.deviceinformation;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.LinkProperties;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.RouteInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import static android.content.Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;

public class NetworkInformation {
    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "NetworkInformation";
    public NetworkInformation(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    /**
     * Get the Ip address of the device.
     * The first method  doesn't require ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission
     * if exception is caught then it will implement other method
     * @return ipAddress in String
     */
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public String getIpAddress(boolean useIPv4){
        int delim = 0;
        String finalAdress = "";
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for(NetworkInterface intf : interfaces){
                List<InetAddress> addresses = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
                for(InetAddress addr : addresses){
                    if(!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
                        boolean isIPv4 = sAddr.indexOf(':') < 0 ;
                        if(useIPv4){
                            if(isIPv4)
                                finalAdress = sAddr;
                        } else {
                            if(!isIPv4){
                                delim = sAddr.indexOf('%');
                                finalAdress =  delim<0 ? sAddr.toUpperCase() : sAddr.substring(0 , delim);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
            finalAdress = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
        }
        return finalAdress;
    }
    private static final String[] FACTORY_DNS_SERVERS = {
            "8.8.8.8",
            "8.8.4.4"
    };
    private static final String METHOD_EXEC_PROP_DELIM = "]: [";
    /**
     * To get all the DNS servers available(With all the methods)
     * Got this code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48973823/15176346
     * Thanks to Grigore Madani for the codes :)
     * @return arrays of DNS Servers
     */
    public String [] getServers() {
        String[] result;
        result = getServersMethodSystemProperties();
        if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
            return result;
        }
        result = getServersMethodConnectivityManager();
        if (result != null && result.length > 0) {

            return result;

        }
        result = getServersMethodExec();
        if (result != null && result.length > 0) {

            return result;

        }
        return FACTORY_DNS_SERVERS;

    }
    private String [] getServersMethodConnectivityManager() {
        // This code only works on LOLLIPOP and higher
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            try {
                ArrayList<String> priorityServersArrayList  = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> serversArrayList          = new ArrayList<>();

                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (connectivityManager != null) {

                    // Iterate all networks
                    // Notice that android LOLLIPOP or higher allow iterating multiple connected networks of SAME type
                    for (Network network : connectivityManager.getAllNetworks()) {

                        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
                        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                            LinkProperties linkProperties    = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(network);
                            List<InetAddress> dnsServersList = linkProperties.getDnsServers();

                            // Prioritize the DNS servers for link which have a default route
                            if (linkPropertiesHasDefaultRoute(linkProperties)) {

                                for (InetAddress element: dnsServersList) {

                                    String dnsHost = element.getHostAddress();
                                    priorityServersArrayList.add(dnsHost);

                                }

                            } else {

                                for (InetAddress element: dnsServersList) {

                                    String dnsHost = element.getHostAddress();
                                    serversArrayList.add(dnsHost);

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

                // Append secondary arrays only if priority is empty
                if (priorityServersArrayList.isEmpty()) {

                    priorityServersArrayList.addAll(serversArrayList);

                }

                // Stop here if we have at least one DNS server
                if (priorityServersArrayList.size() > 0) {

                    return priorityServersArrayList.toArray(new String[0]);

                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Exception detecting DNS servers using ConnectivityManager method", ex);

            }

        }

        // Failure
        return null;

    }

    private String [] getServersMethodSystemProperties() {


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            // This originally looked for all lines containing .dns; but
            // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2207#c73
            // indicates that net.dns* should always be the active nameservers, so
            // we use those.
            final String re1 = "^\\d+(\\.\\d+){3}$";
            final String re2 = "^[0-9a-f]+(:[0-9a-f]*)+:[0-9a-f]+$";
            ArrayList<String> serversArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            try {

                @SuppressLint("PrivateApi") Class SystemProperties = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
                Method method = SystemProperties.getMethod("get", new Class[]{String.class});
                final String[] netdns = new String[]{"net.dns1", "net.dns2", "net.dns3", "net.dns4"};
                for (int i = 0; i < netdns.length; i++) {

                    Object[] args = new Object[]{netdns[i]};
                    String v = (String) method.invoke(null, args);
                    if (v != null && (v.matches(re1) || v.matches(re2)) && !serversArrayList.contains(v)) {
                        serversArrayList.add(v);
                    }

                }

                // Stop here if we have at least one DNS server
                if (serversArrayList.size() > 0) {

                    return serversArrayList.toArray(new String[0]);

                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Exception detecting DNS servers using SystemProperties method", ex);

            }

        }

        // Failed
        return null;

    }

    /**
     * Detect android DNS servers by executing getprop string command in a separate process
     *
     * Notice there is an android bug when Runtime.exec() hangs without providing a Process object.
     * This problem is fixed in Jelly Bean (Android 4.1) but not in ICS (4.0.4) and probably it will never be fixed in ICS.
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688382/runtime-exec-bug-hangs-without-providing-a-process-object/11362081
     *
     * @return Dns servers array
     */
    private String [] getServersMethodExec() {

        // We are on the safe side and avoid any bug
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

            try {

                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop");
                InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
                LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                Set<String> serversSet = methodExecParseProps(lineNumberReader);
                if (serversSet != null && serversSet.size() > 0) {

                    return serversSet.toArray(new String[0]);

                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Exception in getServersMethodExec", ex);

            }

        }

        // Failed
        return null;

    }

    /**
     * Parse properties produced by executing getprop command
     * @param lineNumberReader
     * @return Set of parsed properties
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private Set<String> methodExecParseProps(BufferedReader lineNumberReader) throws Exception {

        String line;
        Set<String> serversSet = new HashSet<String>(10);

        while ((line = lineNumberReader.readLine()) != null) {
            int split = line.indexOf(METHOD_EXEC_PROP_DELIM);
            if (split == -1) {
                continue;
            }
            String property = line.substring(1, split);

            int valueStart  = split + METHOD_EXEC_PROP_DELIM.length();
            int valueEnd    = line.length() - 1;
            if (valueEnd < valueStart) {

                // This can happen if a newline sneaks in as the first character of the property value. For example
                // "[propName]: [\n…]".
                Log.d(TAG, "Malformed property detected: \"" + line + '"');
                continue;

            }

            String value = line.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);

            if (value.isEmpty()) {

                continue;

            }

            if (property.endsWith(".dns") || property.endsWith(".dns1") ||
                    property.endsWith(".dns2") || property.endsWith(".dns3") ||
                    property.endsWith(".dns4")) {

                // normalize the address
                InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(value);
                if (ip == null) continue;
                value = ip.getHostAddress();

                if (value == null) continue;
                if (value.length() == 0) continue;

                serversSet.add(value);

            }

        }

        return serversSet;

    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the specified link properties have any default route
     * @param linkProperties
     * @return true if the specified link properties have default route or false otherwise
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private boolean linkPropertiesHasDefaultRoute(LinkProperties linkProperties) {

        for (RouteInfo route : linkProperties.getRoutes()) {
            if (route.isDefaultRoute()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    // New methods are added from here

    /**
     * @return whether adb debugging is enabled or not in boolean
     */
    public boolean isADBDebuggingEnabled(){
        return Settings.Secure.getInt(this.context.getContentResolver(), "adb_enabled" , 0) > 0 ;
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public boolean isVpnConnection(){
        return Settings.Secure.getInt(this.context.getContentResolver(), "vpn_state", 0) == 1 || isvpn1() || isvpn2();
    }
    private boolean isvpn1() {
        String iface = "";
        try {
            for (NetworkInterface networkInterface : Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())) {
                if (networkInterface.isUp())
                    iface = networkInterface.getName();
                Log.d("DEBUG", "IFACE NAME: " + iface);
                if ( iface.contains("tun") || iface.contains("ppp") || iface.contains("pptp")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private boolean isvpn2() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Network activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetwork();
        NetworkCapabilities caps = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork);
        boolean vpnInUse = caps.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN);
        return vpnInUse;
    }




}
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on what I have tested this is my proposal

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class hostUtil
{
   public static String HOST_NAME = null;
   public static String HOST_IPADDRESS = null;

   public static String getThisHostName ()
   {
      if (HOST_NAME == null) obtainHostInfo ();
      return HOST_NAME;
   }

   public static String getThisIpAddress ()
   {
      if (HOST_IPADDRESS == null) obtainHostInfo ();
      return HOST_IPADDRESS;
   }

   protected static void obtainHostInfo ()
   {
      HOST_IPADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";
      HOST_NAME = "localhost";

      try
      {
         InetAddress primera = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
         String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName ();

         if (!primera.isLoopbackAddress () &&
             !hostname.equalsIgnoreCase ("localhost") &&
              primera.getHostAddress ().indexOf (':') == -1)
         {
            // Got it without delay!!
            HOST_IPADDRESS = primera.getHostAddress ();
            HOST_NAME = hostname;
            //System.out.println ("First try! " + HOST_NAME + " IP " + HOST_IPADDRESS);
            return;
         }
         for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> netArr = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); netArr.hasMoreElements();)
         {
            NetworkInterface netInte = netArr.nextElement ();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> addArr = netInte.getInetAddresses (); addArr.hasMoreElements ();)
            {
               InetAddress laAdd = addArr.nextElement ();
               String ipstring = laAdd.getHostAddress ();
               String hostName = laAdd.getHostName ();

               if (laAdd.isLoopbackAddress()) continue;
               if (hostName.equalsIgnoreCase ("localhost")) continue;
               if (ipstring.indexOf (':') >= 0) continue;

               HOST_IPADDRESS = ipstring;
               HOST_NAME = hostName;
               break;
            }
         }
      } catch (Exception ex) {}
   }
}
```