# How to get MAC(Hardware) address in android programmatically. Not using Bluetooth or Wi-fi

Tags: android, mac-address

I want to get my mac address on my android mobile, without using the Wi-fi or Bluetooth, programmatically in android.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Dont forget to add permission for ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Comment: i want without wifi, For this i have to turn on wifi.

Comment: Read /sys/class/net/[something]/address as a text file
Here is a same question asked before 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191832/get-mac-address-of-android-device-without-wifi/15183653#comment21394080_15183653