# Get ip address (internet dynamic ip)

Tags: android

I try to get internet dynamic IP address with the following code when mobile connection is provided. `getHostAddress` return 10.13.x.x ssid internal host address. But I want to get **as 178.240.x.x dynamic internet IP address**. Thanks in advance.

```
for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
        networkIpAdress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: you will need to ask an external resource for that, like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16781615/2413303

Answer (score 2):

Use this URL to get your public IP address:

```
https://ident.me
```

Note: You might have both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, in which case you can use https://v4.ident.me and https://v6.ident.me respectively.

The documentation is at https://api.ident.me.

Comment: @PierreCarrier: *Who* is the maintainer of *what*? Once you are not the last editor, your name won't show.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my question with following code.

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON");
    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    entity.getContentLength();
    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
    String networkIpAdress = json_data.getString("ip");
```