# Getting external IP address in Android app

Tags: android, ip-address

I need to find my external IP address form within my Android app.
InetAddress.getHostAddress() returns the local network IP address.

I was thinking of something similar to whoamI but can't figure a way to do it short of using and then parsing one of the whoamI sites.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You need to call an external service. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308000/determine-device-public-ip

Comment: you cannot do this just on your own.