# how can i get my external / ip?

Tags: android, http, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get ip address of the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device)

Below is a snippet of how I am trying to get the external IP. However, it does not return anything...

```
public String getIpAddress() {

    try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.whatismyip.com/?404");
            // HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://whatismyip.com.au/");
            // HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.whatismyip.org/");
            HttpResponse response;

            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            //Log.i("externalip",response.getStatusLine().toString());

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            entity.getContentLength();
            str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return str;

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public String getIpAddress() {
String ip;
   try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON");
        // HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://whatismyip.com.au/");
        // HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.whatismyip.org/");
        HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        //Log.i("externalip",response.getStatusLine().toString());

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        entity.getContentLength();
        str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(str);
        ip = json_data.getString("ip");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ip, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e){...}

  return ip;
}
```

OR

UPDATE FEB 2015

WhatIsMyIp now exposes a [developer API](https://www.whatismyip.com/api-documentation/) that you can use.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!.. been stuck here since this morning.. IT FINALLY WORKED... :=

Comment: Ask me any time . android - php problem .  Thanks

Comment: nice..saved me a lot of time.. :)

Comment: Worked like a charm!! +1..Not sure if this api has any daily limit or something..

Comment: But it always returns my ip 127.0.0.1, i tried with emulator and devices:
{"country_code":"RD","hostname":"localhost.localdomain","country_name":"Reserved","ip":"127.0.0.1"}

Comment: The script no longer works

Comment: Why use API? isn't there any code to get the public IP of the user in android?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look here
http://code.google.com/p/external-ip/source/browse/src/org/kost/externalip/ExternalIP.java

and also here 
[External ip address in android programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932427/external-ip-address-in-android-programatically)