# Find IP Address of android device running web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, network-protocols

I have setup a web service in my android device. Now I want to send request to android from a pc through WiFi. I need the ip address of my android device to access it from a pc in the same network. How will I find the IP through my code?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get ip address of the device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get device ip address use this method:

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

if this method returns null, there is no connection available.
If the method returns a string, this string contains the ip address currently used by the device independent of 3G or WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Just found how to get your internal IP:
Settings >> Wireless Controls >> Wi-Fi Settings

At the bottom under "Wi-Fi networks"
tap the connection you are connected to

It brings up a window with info like:

```
Status
Speed
Signal Strength
Security
**IP Address**
```

Comment: Correct, but in DHCP config, this is never guaranteed to remain constant.