# Setting up MAC Address in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, mac-address

How do I setup a MAC address for the Android Emulator?

Currently, it is shown as "Unavailable" under Settings -> About Phone -> Status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Android emulator runs emulating a Ethernet connection, but not a wifi connection. Since the Wifi is not enabled it dosen't have mac address.It's the same as when you try getting a hold of the bluetooth stuff on the emulator. There is no MacAdress and should return null. Try on a real device and it will work

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as when you try getting a hold of the bluetooth stuff on the emulator. There is no MacAdress and should return null. Try on a real device and it will work.

Comment: This answer is copy paste from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10708542/6791222

Answer (score 0):

It does appear to be possible to retrieve the MAC address if that's what you mean by "setup". See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13007325/1489860)

```
Utils.getMACAddress("eth0");
```