# How to find MAC address of an Android device programmatically

Tags: android

How do i get Mac Id of android device programmatically. I have done with IMIE Code and I know how to check Mac id on device manually but have no idea how to find out programmatically.

Comment: I posted here working solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789324/5330408

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically getting the MAC of an Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705906/programmatically-getting-the-mac-of-an-android-device)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Also, add below permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Please refer to [Android 6.0 Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id).

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.
>
> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions.

Comment: You should also give the activity permission ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, otherwise it wont work.

Comment: Word of caution: This will not work if WiFi is disabled in the Settings

Comment: This used to work great, on my nexus 9 running marshmallow this returns 02:00:00:00:00:00 now.

Comment: @AndyB http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id says that this method `WifiInfo.getMacAddress()` will return constant value, so to get mac address in Android M you amy use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32948723/4308151
note that wifi must be on

Comment: If you use this code as-is, you might get this error: The WIFI_SERVICE must be looked up on the Application context or memory will leak on devices < Android N. Try changing  to .getApplicationContext()  [WifiManagerLeak]. The following should work instead: WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: What if I am using cellular data?

Answer (score 21):

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13007325/185565) where I have submitted Utils.java example to provide pure-java implementations and works without WifiManager. Some android devices may not have wifi available or are using ethernet wiring.

```
Utils.getMACAddress("wlan0");
Utils.getMACAddress("eth0");
Utils.getIPAddress(true); // IPv4
Utils.getIPAddress(false); // IPv6
```

Comment: Some devices may have one or more ethernet ports (wired or wireless). This is just a linux jargon naming communication ports. Usuallay Android devices have only one wireless wlan0 port available.

Comment: how to see the name of device port

Comment: See source code in my post getMACAddress, it loops all network interfaces(device ports) you can print out names or do something else with them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device/13007325#13007325

Comment: Does this require some external libs?

Comment: @Hackjustu: This does not require any external libs, altought my original answer is using  InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr) function, it was removed from Android SDK. Instead should use `isIPv4=sAddr.indexOf(':')<0` trick.

Comment: @Whome, when my phone is connected to 4G data, gives null for "wlan0", "eth0" using Utils.getMACAddress("networkInterface")? Is there different networkInterface for 4G or 3G mobile data connection?

Comment: @pcj Devices may use any interface name they want so I suggest you debug printout all the interfaces. See `getMACAddress()` how interfaces are looped. What happens if you call `getMACAddress(null)`?

Comment: @Whome I get following the list of interface name-mac pairs, ip6tnl0-NA, tunl0-NA, wlan0-{VALID_MAC} I am not pasting the mac for security reasons, I have question irrespective of interface MAC is unique for all interfaces or is it unique per interface? Most of the times I am getting MAC using wlan0 interface but some times it returns empty string ( This has observed when 4G data is connected ). MacUtils.getMACAddress(null) also given empty string. Is there any way I will get MAC address always?

Answer (score 11):

With this code you will be also able to get MacAddress in **Android 6.0 also**

```
public static String getMacAddr() {
    try {
        List <NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif: all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b: macBytes) {
                //res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:", b));
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
    return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
}
```

**EDIT 1.**
This answer got a bug where a byte that in hex form got a single digit, will not appear with a "0" before it. The append to res1 has been changed to take care of it.

Answer (score 8):

**It's Working**

```
    package com.keshav.fetchmacaddress;
    
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.NetworkInterface;
    import java.net.SocketException;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            Log.e("keshav","getMacAddr -> " +getMacAddr());
        }
    
        public static String getMacAddr() {
            try {
                List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
                for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
                    if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;
    
                    byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
                    if (macBytes == null) {
                        return "";
                    }
    
                    StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
                    for (byte b : macBytes) {
                        // res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
                        res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b)); 
                    }
    
                    if (res1.length() > 0) {
                        res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
                    }
                    return res1.toString();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //handle exception
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**

This answer got a bug where a byte that in hex form got a single digit, will not appear with a "0" before it. The append to `res1` has been changed to take care of it.

```
 StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : macBytes) {
                    // res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
                    res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b)); 
                }
```

Answer (score 7):

Recent update from Developer.Android.com

> Don't work with MAC addresses MAC addresses are globally unique, not
> user-resettable, and survive factory resets. For these reasons, it's
> generally not recommended to use MAC address for any form of user
> identification. Devices running Android 10 (API level 29) and higher
> report randomized MAC addresses to all apps that aren't device owner
> apps.
>
> Between Android 6.0 (API level 23) and Android 9 (API level 28), local
> device MAC addresses, such as Wi-Fi and Bluetooth, aren't available
> via third-party APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() method and the
> BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress() method both return
> 02:00:00:00:00:00.
>
> Additionally, between Android 6.0 and Android 9, you must hold the
> following permissions to access MAC addresses of nearby external
> devices available via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans:
>
> Method/Property   Permissions Required
>
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or
> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#version_specific_details_identifiers_in_m

Answer (score 4):

Here the Kotlin version of Arth Tilvas answer:

```
fun getMacAddr(): String {
    try {
        val all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())
        for (nif in all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equals("wlan0", ignoreCase=true)) continue

            val macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress() ?: return ""

            val res1 = StringBuilder()
            for (b in macBytes) {
                //res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
                res1.append(String.format("%02X:", b))
            }

            if (res1.length > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length - 1)
            }
            return res1.toString()
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
    }

    return "02:00:00:00:00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private fun getMac(): String? =
        try {
            NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
                    .toList()
                    .find { networkInterface -> networkInterface.name.equals("wlan0", ignoreCase = true) }
                    ?.hardwareAddress
                    ?.joinToString(separator = ":") { byte -> "%02X".format(byte) }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple way:

**Android:**

```
   String macAddress = 
android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), "android_id");
```

**Xamarin:**

```
    Settings.Secure.GetString(this.ContentResolver, "android_id");
```

Comment: Hey
I tried this, but it is giving different macAddress when the apk is built from different laptop