# Retrieving MAC Address Programmatically - Android

Tags: java, android, mac-address

I'm having an issue with retrieving the MAC address of the device programatically, before anyone mentions anything about other posts I have read them already such as: 
[How to find MAC address of an Android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831578/how-to-find-mac-address-of-an-android-device-programatically)

however I tried using the code with my own application and tested it with a simple log.d, only to find that it is returning nothing. The message of "seeing if this works shows" but nothing else. So i am presuming the mac address is null.

```
Log.d("seeing if this works", macAddress2);
```

The code of what I have done is shown here:

```
//Set onclick listener for the Get Mac Address button
        getMac.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                String macAddress2 = wInfo.getMacAddress();

                macAddress.setText(macAddress2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you connected to WiFi when you make the call?  Also, what do you have in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Hey there thank you for the reply and yes I have put that in the manifest

Comment: Strange, I used your code and it worked just fine for me.  You're definitely connected to Wi-Fi?

Comment: Oh really, i am running this through android studio emulator so im presuming it doesnt work on the emulator?

Answer (score 5):

Which Android version are you testing on? The latest(10/2015) [Android M preview](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id) has blocked the app from getting the hardware identifiers for Wifi and Bluetooth.

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.

There is a workaround by reading the Wifi MAC from `/sys/class/net/wlan0/address`, which however will also be blocked in the **Android N** as [claimed by Google](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2427).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static String getMacAddr() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
            if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

            byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
            if (macBytes == null) {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : macBytes) {
                res1.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF) + ":");
            }

            if (res1.length() > 0) {
                res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
            }
            return res1.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
}
```

From here:
http://robinhenniges.com/en/android6-get-mac-address-programmatically

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have put that into my manifest file