# How to get the MAC Address of any android phone?

Tags: javascript, android, macos, asp.net-mvc-3, mac-address

I've seen this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831578/how-to-find-mac-address-of-an-android-device-programatically) on how to get the MAC Address of an android phone but in my case I need to do it in `javascript` or `asp.net mvc3`. I Managed to get the `MAC Address` of the PC through `MVC3` and my problem 1 is solve. This is my second problem in android phones.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a work-around to get the Mac address in Android 6.0.

First you need to add Internet user permission.

Then you can find the mac over the NetworkInterfaces API.

```
public static String getMacAddr() {
  try {
      List<NetworkInterface> all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
      for (NetworkInterface nif : all) {
          if (!nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0")) continue;

          byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
          if (macBytes == null) {
              return "";
          }

          StringBuilder res1 = new StringBuilder();
          for (byte b : macBytes) {
              res1.append(String.format("%02X:",b));
          }

          if (res1.length() > 0) {
              res1.deleteCharAt(res1.length() - 1);
          }
          return res1.toString();
      }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  }
  return "02:00:00:00:00:00";
}
```

Source: http://robinhenniges.com/en/android6-get-mac-address-programmatically