# delphi - android get phone's MAC adress

Tags: delphi

In a fire-monkey (android) application,how can I get the phones MAC address displayed in a Label text  ? Delphi version is Berlin.Android SDK is 25.2.5.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831578/how-to-find-mac-address-of-an-android-device-programmatically

Comment: need it in delphi syntax....

Comment: maybe helpful, dunno.. http://www.fmxexpress.com/access-wifi-device-info-like-ssid-and-ip-address-in-delphi-xe6-firemonkey-on-android/ . just my opinion but Delphi documentation is scarce (and when you do find it, its written in russian) .. Good luck.

Comment: StackOverflow is not really a code translation service. What did you try?

Comment: @FreeConsulting considering the state of Delphi documentation and the relative unpopularity of the tag, I don't think your attitude is very helpful. I feel sorry for the next developer to visit this question, hoping to find an answer, but instead encountering these comments...

Comment: @trooper, developers are usually putting more efforts into their problems.

Comment: @FreeConsulting The goal of this site has always been to build a repository for problems and solutions. Other tags have pretty much been exhausted - there is no reason to ask because the solutions are already there. If this question is not worth the time to answer, at a minimum it should be possible to close it as a duplicate. That would actually be helpful.

Comment: @trooper, well, I'm definitely here not for idle chit-chat. But you feel free to translate given example if you think `[delphi]` isn't "exhausted".

Comment: @FreeConsulting I'm looking for its duplicate right now, but I am not in a position to translate the code myself - I am going to assume using this functionality in Delphi requires JNI - if thats the only way to do it, that in itself is an answer. I'm not here for idle chitchat either, but please understand I'm not new here, the OP isn't new here, and pointing to the solution isn't spoonfeeding anyone. If the tag is truly exhausted, lets find that dupe.

Comment: @FreeConsulting I am being sincere - my experience w/ Delphi wasn't great because there are fewer developers. I like Pascal, but its not easy to find solutions when the language isn't popular. I am going to refer to my initial comment - its not helpful to refuse to acknowledge the question. It would be a good thing for the language (and the community in general) if we could put solutions below these questions, not a bunch of snide remarks.