# How can I know my app was previously installed on a phone?

Tags: android, ios

I am trying to make an app which allows only single account per device. Now what I am trying to know is a property of a phone which never changes. At first I thought I could save MAC address of a device in my database but I read in one of the question on SO that know in android when we try to access MAC address programatically we get a constant that is same for every device. 
I would like to know what never changing property of an android device can I access programatically.

Also in future I would like to develop that app for iOS, is there same non changing property of iOS phone that I can access programatically ?
Thank you.

Comment: That app could have an selling my phone option and the second hand user couldn't use it.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/6950238) answer of [Anthony Forloney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166712/anthony-forloney).

Comment: It says we should use Device id but it may change on factory reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, you have to differentiate between devices.

For Android, you can use Device ID

For IOS, You can use vendor ID [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor).

For IOS : When your app deleted and reinstalled then vendor ID changes so it is better to store your vendor id in keychain using below code.

```
-(NSString *)getUniqueDeviceIdentifier
{

 NSString *yourAppName=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];

 NSString *applicationUUIDStr = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@“Your_App_Name”];
 if (applicationUUIDStr == nil)
 {
    applicationUUIDStr  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"Your_App_Name"];
 }

 return applicationUUIDStr;
}
```

Comment: I strictly want that one account per device thing. People would soon find this thing and could make more than one account per device.

Comment: Use vendor ID. This is the replacement of UDID which apple provides.

Comment: But what about android phones?

Comment: For Android try Device ID. You have to place device check for this purpose.

Comment: How can we find device id ?

Comment: Your answer seems to be good but I am not sure about vendor Id in iOS. Include about android device in your answer and remove that advertising identifier so that I could mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I tried to explain everything in my answer. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure these days you can use mac addresses, however if not have you tried IMEI, i have no idea how this would be done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10831578/4961540 . This question says from marshmallow it is not allowed and what about dual sim phones each sim slot has different IMEI.