# Identifying and saving Mac Address

Tags: android, database, mac-address

i'm a newbie about developing apps and i'm trying to create ones with Android.

I want to do an app that permits to register (normal login) and to take from the phone the Mac Address.

It's not so difficult to create the dabatase and to connect it, the problem is to write the code about the Mac Address.

I explain it better (sorry for my english): i'm a user, i open the app and i register myself with my datas. It saves everything in the fields of the database and, at the same time, it registers in the database also the Mac Address of the phone. I shouldn't want that the user has to search by himself in the phone for the Mac Address but i'd want that the app does it by itself.

Is it possible?

Thank you very much!

Andrew

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find MAC address of an Android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831578/how-to-find-mac-address-of-an-android-device-programmatically)

Comment: Welcome. From Android documentation: [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) - "_the ultimate goal is to identify a particular installation of your app (not the actual physical device)_. **Best practice#1: Avoid using hardware identifiers.**

Comment: Thank you, i have some problem to compile, i'll do a new question