# How can I get MAC address in Android 8 with nativescript?

Tags: android, api, nativescript, mac-address, nic

I need to get MAC address in my nativescript/typescript project on Android platform. I haven't found any plugin to do this so i think the only way is to use native API. Can you provide me the code in typescript to do this? Thanks

Comment: Use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10831640/4936697 but of course, you need to convert the Java code to TypeScript (look for documentation about the marshaling in NativeScript)

Comment: This talks about Android 6, I need for Android 8.1.0 :/ The code for 8.1.0 is more difficult to translate

Comment: Ouch you are right.. it returns a constant dummy value instead of the real MAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (tested on Android 10)

```
try {
    const collection = java.util.Collections.list(java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
    const iterator = collection.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      const nif = iterator.next(),
        name = nif.getName();

      if (name !== "wlan0") {
        continue;
      }

      const macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
      if (macBytes !== null) {

        const res = new java.lang.StringBuilder();
        for (let i = 0; i < macBytes.length; i++) {
          const b = macBytes[i];
          const hex = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF);
          if (hex.length == 1) { hex = "0" + hex; }
          res.append(hex + ":");
        }

        if (res.length > 0) {
          res.deleteCharAt(res.length - 1);
        }

        console.log("Mac address: " + res);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
```