WifiConfiguration getRandomizedMacAddress() returns default value 02:00:00:00:00:00
I understand that Android does not want to give access to the actual MAC address due to security concerns. But I don't understand why even the randomized MAC address can't be accessed programmatically especially when this randomized MAC address is visible and used by other network devices. I tried WifiConfiguration().getRandomizedMacAddress() but only got back 02:00:00:00:00:00 in return.
This link mentions the restrictions of WifiConfiguration's getRandomizedMacAddress() method, but doesn't give an explanation as to why there is a restriction.
Is there a way to programmatically access the randomized MAC address of your Android device? Can someone share why there are restrictions for the randomized MAC address in addition to the actual MAC address?

Rather than using the constructor (which I am surprised is public), have you tried getting it from WifiManager, such as via getConfiguredNetworks()?

This was a way to get the MAC address in the past but now also returns a constant value. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10831640/5083012 I'm looking for a way to get the randomized MAC address. If the randomized MAC address is also hidden, then I'd like to understand why, since this address is visible by other WiFi-enabled devices.

Have you tried using a WifiManager method, such as getConfiguredNetworks(), that returns a WifiConfiguration (which has getRandomizedMacAddress()), rather than a WifiInfo (which does not)?

I tried it. It returns 0 and the methods are deprecated.

Using WifiManager and getScanResults() I get back a list of all WiFi enabled devices nearby but does not include my own device.
