# how to find IP Address of the android device?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get ip address of the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device)

Is it possible or not using some program?
 it is my code

```
TextView ip_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
WifiManager wifimanager= (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
List<String> lsit =  wifimanager.getConfiguredNetworks(); 
WifiConfiguration wc = (String)lsit.get(0); 
ip_address.setText("\n"+ Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifimanager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()));
```

Comment: what output u r getting with this code?

Comment: Have you added the permission in your manifest?

Comment: what problem/error are you facing with above code? and dont forget to add Internet permission in manifest file.