# how to obtain the ip address of the connected wifi router in android programmatically?

Tags: android, eclipse, ip-address, android-wifi, wifimanager

I want to obtain the ip address of the the wifi router to which my android phone is connected? I know that we can get the mac/BSSId and SSID by using the android APIS but I don't find the way to find the way to find the ip address of it?

I found the code for obtaining the ip address of phone owns wifi router

```
WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo myWifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int ipAddress = myWifiInfo.getIpAddress();
System.out.println("WiFi address is " + android.text.format.Formatter.formatIpAddress(ipAddress))
```

but failed to get what I want

Comment: try this soln. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6071963/735675

Comment: what did you get using the given code? and what did you want to get?

Comment: Have you added permissions?I'm sure there's no problems in your code.

Comment: @paritybit I want to get ip address of the router so that i can connect to the other android phone which is connected to the same router

Comment: @klaudo I just want a way to start it...i want a method for it so i can start coding for it..

Comment: @Dya bro this will give the ip address of the android device ..i want the ip address of the router to which it is connected

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you likely want is [`DhcpInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/DhcpInfo.html):

```
final WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) super.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
final DhcpInfo dhcp = manager.getDhcpInfo();
final String address = Formatter.formatIpAddress(dhcp.gateway);
```

This will yield the (formatted) gateway IP address, which *should* be what you're looking for.

Comment: This is great easy solution, and the main goal - it's works. But  unfortunately, it does not support IPv6

Comment: its giving me the local ip address

Answer (score 4):

Since formatIpAddress is Deprecatted, here is the alternative :

```
public String getHotspotAdress(){
    final WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)super.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    final DhcpInfo dhcp = manager.getDhcpInfo();
    int ipAddress = dhcp.gateway;
    ipAddress = (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)) ?
            Integer.reverseBytes(ipAddress) : ipAddress;
    byte[] ipAddressByte = BigInteger.valueOf(ipAddress).toByteArray();
    try {
        InetAddress myAddr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddressByte);
        return myAddr.getHostAddress();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("Wifi Class", "Error getting Hotspot IP address ", e);
    }
    return "null"
}
```