# Delphi Android WIFI connectivity status

Tags: delphi

I was wondering if there is any way to show the connectivity status with the router, for example see how good it's speeds are, its ping, latency etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001449/how-to-obtain-the-ip-address-of-the-connected-wifi-router-in-android-programmati for a way to find the IP address of the WiFi router

Comment: @mjn42 I was wondering on how to show the ping, latency etc.

Comment: As you wrote "status with the router" I understood that you need to show data about the WiFi part of the communication

Comment: Seems to be some relevant suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119345/how-to-measure-latency-in-a-wifi-network-java-android, which should be easy enough to do in Delphi