# How to get android device connected data network adapter name, ip and type of network?

Tags: android

Requirement is:
Need following parameters from android device connected network
1) network ip
2) network type
3) network adapter name

Could you please suggest me to get above params in Java or C.

Comment: Some android devices having two active data networks like WIFI and LTE...Device giving two interface ip's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Android network interface IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545392/get-android-network-interface-ip-address)