# How to get User IP address surfing internet on my Android App through his phone/tablet

Tags: java, android, mobile, ip

I have created an Android app which uses WebView to load internet pages. I want to get the mobile user IP Address. How to do it??

Comment: you should think of googling your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device

Comment: what you want surfing website ip or your device ip???

Comment: Thnks @Guian ... dunno how i missed it.

Comment: @altaf I want device IP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static String getipAddress() { 
            try {
                for (Enumeration en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                    for (Enumeration enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                        if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                            String ipaddress=inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                            Log.e("ip address",""+ipaddress);
                            return ipaddress;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Log.e("Socket exception in GetIP Address of Utilities", ex.toString());
            }
            return null; 
    }
```

Also add in mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Am getting casting error at two places: `NetworkInterface intf = **(NetworkInterface)** en.nextElement();`                                    `InetAddress inetAddress = **(InetAddress)** enumIpAddr.nextElement();`

Answer (score 0):

This will load ip address on screen

```
 webview.loadUrl("http://www.whatismyip.com")
```