# How to capture the IP address of Android Application end user

Tags: android, eclipse, ip-address

**--> IP address of Android Application end user**

I have searched allot over internet about how to capture the  **IP ADDRESS** of user who is actually using my ANDROID APPLICATION, but did not get the correct code which will work for me.

I am developing this android app on Eclipse.

on most of the forums i get this link which is not reachable at all:
http://www.droidnova.com/get-the-ip-address-of-your-device,304.html

Need your support guys.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you want ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device Utils.getIPAddress(true); // IPv4
Utils.getIPAddress(false); // IPv6

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following code.

```
  public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
      for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
         NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
         for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
           InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
           if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
             String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());
             return ip;
           }
         }
      }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
      // 
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Don't forget to add the following permission in order to allow your application to open network sockets:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: @Ankur - I am getting this error "The method formatIpAddress(int) from the type Formatter is deprecated" on this line "getting String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());"

Comment: Switch the Formatter line CT talked about to: String ip = inetAddress.getHostAddress(); to avoid the deprecation warning

Answer (score 1):

1. try to open a connection to http://www.whatismyip.com and fetch the result.
2. Make a HTTP POST ( or GET) to your app host and check there from which IP is coming the request.
3. use SDK.

Edit: based on comment: that is the server side role to get the client IP, not the Android job.
Here is a sample how can you do it with PHP: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: i have tried it, but i need to capture (stored) the IP address of user who will use my Android application.

Comment: which one have you tryed and where do you need to store it: Android or server side?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i need to store it on my Server, just of keep the logs with IP address of users who have used my app.

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of requesting the IP from the Server, you can tell your phone to send the IP.

You can get the IP adress with the following code.

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                        .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e(tag, ex.toString());
        }
        return "";
    }
```