# Getting My LAN ip address (192.168.xxxx) (IPV4)

Tags: java, android, inetaddress

In my android device I am trying to find its IP address(IPV4).
  If I do the following code

```
InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println(inet.getHostAddress()); //giving me 127.0.0.1
```

The code is giving me 127.0.0.1.
I wanted to get the actual IP 198.168.xx.xx.

(In My pc the same code giving me the actual IP though.)

Comment: [OT] sorry but hiding a private IP (192.168.xxx?) is not necessary, you can't be hacked by people that knows that info.

Comment: @GrailsGuy Not duplicate to that, OP wants 192.168 local network address and not the public router address.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know, I was lazy to put that there.

Comment: The answer of DigitalRounin is very useful for your purpose. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730711/get-my-wifi-ip-address-android/18638588#18638588)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
public static String getIpAddress() { 
            try {
                for (Enumeration en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                    for (Enumeration enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                        if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()&&inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                            String ipAddress=inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                            Log.e("IP address",""+ipAddress);
                            return ipAddress;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Log.e("Socket exception in GetIP Address of Utilities", ex.toString());
            }
            return null; 
    }
```

**Give permissions**

Also add in mainfest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply.
I am getting "fe80::2064:32ff:fe5d:2edf%p2p0" as my address.
Is it ipv6 address. how to get ipv4 address?

Comment: +1 for checking all the interfaces. This will take care of both wifi and cellular interfaces

Comment: @VishnudevK Thats because ur router is configured for ipv6 Address.

Comment: @Ayush but in phone's status its showing the ipv4 address only.
is there any way to convert it to ipv4.

Comment: @VishnudevK ipv4 and ipv6 Both are Different thing, they CANT BE CONVERTED.

Comment: @ayush got it. see the change I made

Comment: @VishnudevK I have edited the question since the answer is for IPV4 only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to get your IP address.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
return String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),
        (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
```

This returns it as a String in the form "X.X.X.X"

The only permission you need in your `manifest.xml` is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: And if he is not using WiFi?

Comment: What's an example of a device that doesn't use wifi to get an internal LAN address? 198.168.xx.xx. Ethernet port?

Comment: As often, I concentrate in the body of the question and miss data from the header (it is the only place where the `LAN` part is informed). And yes, an ethernet port is possible (though I agree that it is not that frequent nowadays).

Comment: :) np I understand. In my experience the code I posted works very well in production on Android devices to do exactly what the user asked.