# JmDNS service not found in ZeroConf browser

Tags: java, android, zeroconf, jmdns

I'm developing a web app in Java (with Spark) and I want it to use JmDNS to be able to find this server in my Android app. I was following steps from [JmDNS page](https://github.com/jmdns/jmdns) with service registration, and my code looks like this:

```
try {
        // Create a JmDNS instance
        JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost());

        // Register a service
        ServiceInfo serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create("_http._tcp.local.", "smart_dom", 4567, "path=index.html");
        jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I implemented the part about discovering services in my Android app, but it finds nothing. I made some changes according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805893/android-jmdns-doesnt-discover-devices), and even downloaded ZeroConf Browser (it relies on JmDNS), but even this app doesn't see my web app.

My server runs on Windows PC. I know that Windows doesn't support mDNS, but Java should be independant from the platform. What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was wondering what was wrong, I found the answer.

In my case the problem was with `JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost());`, especially with `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` which returned 127.0.0.1 not my LAN adapter wi-fi address. The problem was solved using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252018/getting-my-lan-ip-address-192-168-xxxx-ipv4) solution. It bases on looking for the correct interface via `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`.

Comment: 20 days later, it just stopped working. No reason... Code didn't change. JmDNS doesn't detect any service from other devices again...