# Is it possible to get the IP of the device irrespective of the device?

Tags: android

Can I get the IP address of the device somehow without asking for premission to do a connection with this device?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because you need to access the network interfaces in order to get their IP.

You can find a solution with the usage of permissions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730711/get-my-wifi-ip-address-android)

Comment: True. You don't need a permission "to do a connection" but just `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` to just "access" network state.