# Android how to get Network/Wi-Fi IP

Tags: android, android-networking

I have a question I want get my mobile IP

whether is Network or Wi-Fi

And I try some way , but I don't know why I can't get it

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getLocalIpAddress();
    }
    public String getLocalIpAddress(){
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                            InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()){
                                    Log.e("IP", inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString());
                                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                                }
                    }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e( "Error:" , ex.toString());
          }
        return null ;
        }
}
```

And this is my Log

```
fe80::a3c8:4c03:154:8e1d%rmnet_usb0
```

And this is my AndroidManifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.INTERNET" />  
    <uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get my wifi ip address Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730711/get-my-wifi-ip-address-android)

Comment: @PiotrGolinski Yes this way can gey wifi address but I can't get 3G IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for getting device ip address:

```java
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Comment: this way can get wifi but I want get 3G address

Comment: plz try this it may  help you?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, it may help you:

```java
public String getLocalIpAddress()
{
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("IP Address", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Add below permission in the manifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: this way will get the msg : fe80::a3c8:4c03:154:8e1d%rmnet_usb0

Comment: Plz go refer this                                                         http://www.technocrazed.com/android-find-and-display-ip-address-of-a-mobile-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
private String getIPAddress(Context context) {

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    return Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
}
```

Comment: this way can get wifi but I want get 3G address