# Direct SQL Server Access From .NET Maui App

Tags: maui

I'm trying to think through how to build a .NET Maui app I want to do.  My sticking point is figuring out how to approach access to the database.  It needs a shared database, but I want to keep deployment as simple as possible, so I was thinking of a process like customer provisions their own SQL Server database through something like Azure, they download my app, they enter the database connection info when first launching the app, and then the app creates the database and seeds the data it needs to.  The customer could then add additional instances of the app (i.e. other devices) to this same database in the same way.

I'm seeing all sorts of posts saying that an app directly accessing the database is bad though.  I'm trying to understand why exactly.  The only reason I can think of is if I was hosting the database.  If it was my database, people could get at the connection info if they wanted to from the app.  In this scenario though, the user of my app would be the owner of the database.

My question is, what am I missing?  If it isn't a database I'm hosting, why is it bad?  What would I be opening myself up to if I went down this route?

Comment: for a mobile app to access a DB, it must exist on a server that is on the open internet.  This is a recipe for disaster.  Best practice is to use a services layer that exists between the mobile app and the db to provide an additional layer of security, control, etc.  Even if you're not hosting it yourself, if your customer's database is breached because of your poor app design, expect to receive a call from their lawyers

Comment: The intent wouldn't be to have the database exposed over the internet.  It would be the customer's database, so I was hoping I could use some combination of firewall rules or vpn to limit access to it.

Comment: Did this [Connect SQL Server using .NET MAUI and perform CRUD operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78102762/net-maui-android-how-to-get-user-to-select-wi-fi-network) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I haven't seen this one before.  There is a comment in the middle that I think does.  All the other links I've seen basically say don't directly access the database, so I was trying to get a more detailed "why" to that.  This link seems to imply that it depends on use case and if done right, is fine.  Thanks again!