# Accesso to a dynamic URL by an Android APP apk

Tags: android, url, apk, kiosk

i need to create an apk that open the follow URL:
xxx.yyy.zzz.245

where xxx.yyy.zzz. is the same of the Android device that i'm using, is there an easy way to do it?

Basically i have to move the same device (kiosked) in different network where the server is always 245 (unfortunately cannot use the DNS in those network)

I trayed to write the apk code but it work only with static IpUrl (for me it's impossibile to use like this due the number of different networks)

Comment: I assume you are talking about an IP assigned to Wifi. Why don't you just get the current Wifi IP and use it to modify it and build your URL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16730711/150978

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.