# Get IP Address in Android

Tags: android, getjson

I'm implementing application  for getting the IP Address of my device/mobile in my android app  from PHP. I'm using httpGet() method for getting the Ip Address. I got NullPointerException in my logcat.

Here is my code.

```
public class Code_Demo extends Activity
{
    Button btnSubmitCode;
    EditText editText_Code;
    TextView textView_ReadCode;
    String pref_filename="code_file";
    String strReadFile;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.code);

        editText_Code=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edText_Code);
        textView_ReadCode=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_ReadCode);

        btnSubmitCode=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Submit);
        btnSubmitCode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String strCode = editText_Code.getText().toString().trim();
                create_File(strCode);

                if(editText_Code.getText().toString().isEmpty()) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                SharedPreferences sharedPref1 =getSharedPreferences(pref_filename, 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref1.edit();
                editor.putString("code",strCode);
                Log.e("Editor Num 1:", strCode);
                editor.commit();
                //readFile();

                try 
                {
                    getIp_Address();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent_CodeDemo = new Intent(Code_Demo.this , Gsk_Demo.class);
                startActivity(intent_CodeDemo);
            }
        });

    } // onCreate() method end here



    //Get Ip Address

    public void getIp_Address() throws IOException
    {
        HttpGet httppost1 = new HttpGet("http://api.externalip.net/ip");
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try 
        {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost1);
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);
        InputStream is = buf.getContent();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String ipaddress = r.readLine();
        Log.e("ipaddress",ipaddress);
    }
}
```

Here Is My LogCat which i got nullPointerException

```
11-13 15:51:04.245: W/KeyCharacterMap(1077): No keyboard for id 0
11-13 15:51:04.245: W/KeyCharacterMap(1077): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-13 15:51:05.631: E/Editor Num 1:(1077): gskhmjd
11-13 15:51:05.662: D/AndroidRuntime(1077): Shutting down VM
11-13 15:51:05.662: W/dalvikvm(1077): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.gsk.Code_Demo.getIp_Address(Code_Demo.java:94)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.gsk.Code_Demo$1.onClick(Code_Demo.java:71)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-13 15:51:05.671: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please avoid HTTP-Tasks in the UI-Thread! Use a AsyncTask instead. I think you get a NetworkOnMainThread Exception before so your response is null

Comment: And please post your LogCat and highlight the Line where your NullPointer is thrown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device

Comment: I ahve post my log cat information.

Comment: @A.S i have post my log_cat stack trace information.

Comment: at com.gsk.Code_Demo.getIp_Address(Code_Demo.java:94) Where is it?

Comment: i have already post my all code with getIp_Address() method. And  getIp_Address() in my Code_Demo Activity.

Comment: `response = httpclient.execute(httppost1);` where did you initialize the `httpclient`?

Comment: My code is work properly and I'm getting  ip address .

Comment: Thank you so much giving me the idea of using Async Task.Thanks so much.