# Alternative for Formatter.formatIpAddress(int);

Tags: android

I'd used this code in my application, but the warning says its :
*"The method formatIpAddress(int) from the type Formatter is deprecated"*

```
android.text.format.Formatter.formatIpAddress(mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

what's the quick fix for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12449111/13082664

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[The documentation states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Formatter.html#formatIpAddress%28int%29)

> Use getHostAddress(), which supports both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. This method does not support IPv6 addresses.

where `getHostAddress()` refers to [`InetAddress.getHostAddress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29).

However, [`WifiInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html)  just has a ipv4 address as an `int` and AFAIK there's no practical way to convert it to an `InetAddress`. The deprecation is because the function doesn't support ipv6 but neither does `WifiInfo`. So I'd say just use `formatIpAddress()` because it works and add `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` to get rid of the warning.

Comment: how to use the InetAddress anyway @laalto?

Answer (score 25):

```
WifiInfo wifiinfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
byte[] myIPAddress = BigInteger.valueOf(wifiinfo.getIpAddress()).toByteArray();
// you must reverse the byte array before conversion. Use Apache's commons library
ArrayUtils.reverse(myIPAddress);
InetAddress myInetIP = InetAddress.getByAddress(myIPAddress);
String myIP = myInetIP.getHostAddress();
```

So myIP should be what you want.

Comment: ArrayUtils.reverse is not found? missing something?

Comment: @AlpAltunel as mentioned in above code comment, i used ArrayUtils by Apache commons. see here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to Muhammad Riyaz approach:

```
String ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(
    ByteBuffer
        .allocate(Integer.BYTES)
        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        .putInt(manager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress())
        .array()
    ).getHostAddress();
```

This way you don't have to use Apache's commons library.

Answer (score 2):

it was deprecated from api level 12 in favour of `[getHostAdress();][1]`. So I suggest to add the suppresswarning annotation and do the following thing:

```
String myIpString = null;
if (apilevel < 12) {
    myIpString = formatIpAddress(...);
} else {
    myIpString = getHostAdress();
}
```

you can get the api level of the device this way:

```
int apiLevel = Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);
```

Comment: even the SDK variable is also deprecated! @blackbelt

Comment: android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK was deprecated in favor of android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, IIRC

Answer (score 0):

```
val ip = (InetAddress.getByAddress(ByteArray(4, { i ->
        (connectionInfo.ipAddress
            .shr(i * 8).and(255)).toByte()
    })) as Inet4Address).hostAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

Also without any additional dependencies (notice the different `Context` used):

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) requireContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int ip = wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
byte[] buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(ip).array();

try {
    String dotNotation = InetAddress.getByAddress(buffer).getHostAddress();
} catch (UnknownHostException ignore) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to use `InetAddress.getHostAddress()` to get it working with both `IPv4` and `IPv6`

```kotlin
// Start by creating an `InetAddress` Object
val inetAddress= InetAddress.getByAddress(wifiManager.connectionInfo.ipAddress.toReversedByteArray())

// this will return a string representation of your ip address
val ipAddress = inetAddress.hostAddress 

// cast an int IpAddress into byte array
fun Int.toReversedByteArray() = toBigInteger().toByteArray().reversedArray()
```

Comment: Both `connectionInfo` and `ipAddress` will be deprecated, any new ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Both `getConnectionInfo()` and `getIpAddress()` will be deprecated, here I post the latest solution to get the Wifi ip address:

```
object ConnectivityHelper {
    fun Context.getConnectivityManager() = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    fun getIpAddress(context: Context) = with(context.getConnectivityManager()) {
        getLinkProperties(activeNetwork)!!.linkAddresses[1].address.hostAddress!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin:**

```
 private fun getLocalIpAddress(): String? {
        try {
            val en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
            while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
                val enumIpAddress = en.nextElement().inetAddresses
                while (enumIpAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    val inetAddress = enumIpAddress.nextElement()
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress && inetAddress is Inet4Address) {
                        return inetAddress.hostAddress
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: SocketException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
```

**Java:**

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Get rid of the warning by adding @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static String getLocalAddress()
{
    String iIPv4 = "";

    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) theContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    iIPv4 = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());

    return iIPv4;
}
```