# getIpAddress() returns 0.0.0.0. in android studio .Why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi

Creating `WifiManager`

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Getting `ipAddress`

```
 String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

And displaying in `textview`

```
 textview.setText("Your Device IP Address: " + ipAddress);
```

Comment: We need code snippet to answer that WHY!?

Comment: Are you using Emulator or Real device?

Comment: Have you added Internet Permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26402397/7176189

Comment: @frankenstein  I used both Emulator and Real device shows same.

Comment: @MehulKabaria Yes, I added 3 permissions  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: @jaikhambhayta shows formatIpAddress() deprecated is that the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846328/7176189

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to get IP address of the device pass true for IPv4 and false for IPv6

```
public static String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4) {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
                    //boolean isIPv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr);
                    boolean isIPv4 = sAddr.indexOf(':')<0;

                    if (useIPv4) {
                        if (isIPv4) 
                            return sAddr;
                    } else {
                        if (!isIPv4) {
                            int delim = sAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 zone suffix
                            return delim<0 ? sAddr.toUpperCase() : sAddr.substring(0, delim).toUpperCase();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>` in AndroidManifest.xml file, It will give you the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simulator or real device, you need to check this device has use wifi or network connection.
If you don't know which device is using the network
you need get all network and check IP, it has, so returns IP

```
public String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4) {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
                    //boolean isIPv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr);
                    boolean isIPv4 = sAddr.indexOf(':')<0;

                    if (useIPv4) {
                        if (isIPv4) 
                            return sAddr;
                    } else {
                        if (!isIPv4) {
                            int delim = sAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 zone suffix
                            return delim<0 ? sAddr.toUpperCase() : sAddr.substring(0, delim).toUpperCase();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";
 }
```

In AndroidManifest, add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in Manifest

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Make sure that `Formatter` library should be this

```
  import android.text.format.Formatter
```

Nothing wrong  with your code. Just make sure this thing