# Restrict android application to specific region

Tags: android, region, restriction

I want my application to work in specific region e.g US.

We can limit distribution of application from play market but i found there are some hacks to install those apps.

I have to somehow limit the use within application.

For that I can retrieve user's GPS location and use Google's Geocode API for first run. But what if user travels to some other region?

I will have to use Location change listener to cater this scenario, but this will drain battery.

If I go for device's timezone, User can change it.

Is there any other thing i can possibly do to restrict application to specific region?

Comment: Maybe try filtering the users by using Mobile carrier? e.g Country Code or something along those lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check for the network the user is registered on with `TelephonyManager`

You have 2 methods that can be helpful.

> GetNetworkCountryIso
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso()

and

> GetSimCountryIso
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso()

**Explanation**

`getNetworkCountryIso()` will give you the iso for the country which the user is currenty registered for. 

*ie: If you're from Albania (al) and went to travel to USA (us) this will return "us"*

`getSimCountryIso()` will give you the iso for the country where the  SIM provider's country code.. 
*ie: If you're from Albania (al) and went to travel to USA (us) this will return "al"*

**UPDATE**

You can integrate (if server side available) http://www.whois.net/ip-address-lookup/ to look for the device IP address. You can get the IP like this.

> [How to get IP address of the device from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device)

With a combination of all this functions (Wifi, network provider, IP, GPS, Google Play regions) you can reduce a lot the use limitations of your app. In the other hand if the user it´s advance enough to fake the IP using a proxy, doesn't turn on the Wifi / GPS and doesn't have SIM card, there´s not much more to do.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That is really encouraging but what if user do not have any SIM card installed?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadUmair updated my answer, I'm sorry to tell you that there´s not much left to do.

Comment: That will be very rare case, but for that we can check for installed apps to detect of any famous VPN is installed:)

Answer (score 0):

As a continuation to my comment, you could go by those lines of filtering users by country code.

The problem - only some carriers store the phone number on the actual SIM card. If so, you will be able to obtain it using

```
 TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

To avoid the instances of those carriers who don't store the actual number on the SIM - there is no way to retrieve the number seeing it is not stored on the phone.
So, what I would do, is simply on the first run of application, request the user to input his full phone number (including country code) - and store that in SharedPrefs. Then, you will know if to run the app or not.

Good luck, hope this has helped!

Comment: Requesting user for his number will allow him to fake his region

Comment: True, but the chances are that he WILL give in a fake number are not high.

Comment: well, chances to install app with distribution limit using hack is much lower then yours, but i am willing to cater maximum possibilities.