# how to get the mac address of the device in android at without internet connection

Tags: android, wifi

How to get the mac address in the absence of the wifi!! and am using the following code to get the mac address in the presence of the wifi `public static String getMACaddress(Context ctx)
                {

```
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

            if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) 
            {
            WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress(); 
            }
        `
```

in the else part i want to get the mac address in the normal way i mean without the internet  connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below post.. In this without using of wifi connection getting mac address.may it will help you.

```
// AndroidManifest.xml permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

// test functions
Utils.getMACAddress("wlan0");
Utils.getMACAddress("eth0");
Utils.getIPAddress(true); // IPv4
Utils.getIPAddress(false); // IPv6
```

[How to get IP address of the device from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device/13007325#13007325)

Comment: @Tripathi   fine thank you !!! but i want to pass the address as the string  and i have to dispaly in the textview but in the above how can i pass ? please can you give a brief ??  and also also they have given the two different adress What it mean of "wlan0" and "eth0" ?

Comment: the return type of method getIPAddress() is string so you can store it string and then show in your textview..

Comment: Utils.getMACAddress("wlan0");
Utils.getMACAddress("eth0"); not working retun null