# ping command variation for checking connectivity using the destination nodes MAC address

Tags: java, android, networking

I'm trying to develop an application which needs to  check connectivity with another of my android device but via the destinations MAC address. 
Is it possible? Any pointers?

I'm primarily using my wifi and both my devices are connected to the same wifi. but as i have enabled DHCP, I don't always have the same static IP on both my devices. and i dont intend to use static IPs either. Thus i figured using the MAC address would be better.

I don't have any code to show yet. but any pointers will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the solution offered to this question. You can use the java code to read the IP and MAC addresses from the special linux file. It requires API level 9 and above though! Based on the comments, the solution did work.

[Q: How to get IP address of the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device)

I not sure about logging and scitching between dynamic IP addresses but MAC address should do the trick.