# How to append the IP (dynamically) to the connection String?

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I have an android app that connects to the `MySQL` through `jdbc`,I use connection string where I want to append the IP to it by detecting innetwork.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+  port + "/" + dbname;
```

where port and dbname are hardcoded,where IP is retrieved by a method and stored in `host` variable.

I can able to print the connection string through `Toast.maketext()` and it displayes perfectly,but while connecting to db it shows a nullpointer exception.

Comment: Please provide more code

Comment: Regarding which one ? Because I'm 100% sure that the string is perfectly displayed in the Toast.

Comment: A NullPointerException means that you want to use something that has not been initialized. So my guess is that this has nothing to do with the connection string.

Comment: sorry mate! I tried all possible solutions,its printing perfectly in the toast but not connecting to database.

Comment: Please, provide connection routine code.

Comment: connection routine ? which one ?

Comment: Block that contains `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` and `DriverManager.getConnection();` statements.

Comment: con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"abc","abc")

Comment: @user3819356 how to convert an IP to a string format? I guess the issue is there.

Comment: Provide the whole block of code where you obtain IP, store it in the `host` variable and request connection to the DB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device

Comment: I followed the above link.I found out that it retrieves the Gateway no the IPv4 address.

Comment: Use an IDE and set appropriate breakpoints to determine what variable is null. Also, the stacktrace of the exception should tell you exactly what line it is on