# Where are IP addresses stored on Android?

Tags: android, ip-address, store

Where are IP addresses stored on an Android device? In what location on disk, or otherwise; how are they stored?

Comment: try this forum: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The user of your device can set a static ip for every wifi connection in the settings.

Comment: On my device it is not possible to set a static IP in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP addresses on Android are normally stored as an entry in:
/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db

sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

For statically configured networks (i.e., not DHCP which doesn't store), addresses are stored in `/data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt`, managed by `WifiConfigStore` class. This is not a public API and is only used from class `WifiStateMachine`.  However, you can find out the format of this file by viewing the source: [WifiConfigStore.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiConfigStore.java#WifiConfigStore).

Comment: I think this may be device-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Because Android is based on a Linux System, the IPs are stored inside the system. 
So it's the same way like in Linux *( keyword: ifconifg )*

But you can get the IP like shown here: [IP details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device)

Comment: I want to set a static persistent IP for my device. Where is the config file for that located then? Can't find anything.

Comment: Can I configure a persistent static IP address for a specific interface using setprop?

Comment: Yeah it was way more informative before the edit disappeared.