# How do I obtain my local udp ip address on Android using Boost Asio?

Tags: android, c++, network-programming, udp, boost-asio

I'm working on a simple communication client in-between *Windows/Android* using [Boost-Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and *UDP*. When resolving the hostname and ip address on Windows I get my computer name and a valid ip-address. However, the equivalent code on android returns `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.
How can I obtain an ip-address usable from other clients?

*Snippet for obtaining local ip address*

```
  auto io_service = asio::io_service();
  auto resolver = asio::ip::udp::resolver(io_service);
  const auto host_name = asio::ip::host_name(); // "localhost" on android
  const auto query = asio::ip::udp::resolver::query(host_name, "");
  const auto begin = resolver.resolve(query);
  const auto end = asio::ip::udp::resolver::iterator{};
  for (
    auto it = resolver.resolve(query);
    it != end;
    ++it
  ) { auto ip = it->endpoint().address(); } // only 127.0.0.1 on android
```

*Android Manifest:*

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

*Notes*

I do find the correct ip-address via the *Java WifiManager*. However, I would like to obtain it directly from the `C++/boost::asio` side of my application where the rest of the network code is.

Comment: Minor thing I want to know, did you test your app on real device or Android Emulator?

Comment: On a real device :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried to code in C++ for Android, but rather in ReactJS or directly in Java where a way of obtaining the IP would be e.g.

> ```
> WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
> String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
> ```

What I am saying is that you should most probably be obtaining the IP from the **WifiManager as authoritative source under Android** - that is what my I keep hearing from Android gurus. Given that you want to stick to `boost::asio`, let's have a closer look to your library.

If you look into the source code of Boost-Asio, e.g. at [`boost/asio/ip/host_name.hpp`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/asio/ip/host_name.hpp) I see a *single* call of `boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::gethostname(name, sizeof(name), ec)` which is located 
within [`asio/detail/socket_ops.hpp`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/asio/detail/socket_ops.hpp). I was expecting a loop over all possible sockets since there can be multiple interfaces. It is not obvious to me which order the sockets/ interfaces have under Android.

In other words: Maybe under Android your library is just (un)lucky to get the wrong socket which happens to be the loopback interface with `127.0.0.1` as IP.
You could now write your own `asio::ip::gethostname()` function which tries to query the underlying `asio::detail::socket_ops::gethostname()` more than once.

### References

- [How to get IP address of the device from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/)  and its duplicate [How to get the ip address of an android mobile programatically ....?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402218/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-an-android-mobile-programatically)
- https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/885603/view.html talks about a similar issue  of the Unreal Engine. Different system, same effect.
- Official documentation for Android networking: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/networking
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/is-there-a-command-or-application-similar-to-ipconfig