# Getting IP Address while using mobile data in android

Tags: android

Anybody help me to get IP Address whenever I use mobile data. When I am using wifi then I am getting IP Address, but while using mobile data its not working.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Didnt get the answer..

Comment: Does the answer I've given work? Seems to work for other people

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IP address of the device from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code)

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/a5loFkRuV3w

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() { 
        try { 
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = 
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en 
                    .hasMoreElements();) { 
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement(); 
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = 
intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr 
                        .hasMoreElements();) { 
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement 
(); 
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { 
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString 
(); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } catch (SocketException ex) { 
            Log.e(S.TAG, ex.toString()); 
        } 
        return null; 
    }
```

Although I havent tried it myself