# getting mobile network ip address

Tags: android

hello i'm using this method to get mobile network IP address

```
public static String getMobileIPAddress() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return  addr.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { } // for now eat exceptions

    return "";
}
```

but the return value does not seems to be IP : fe80::dc19:94ff:fe6f:ae7b%dummy0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code is correct. It's getting list of `InetAddresses` where **ip address** also present with **mac address**. You have to use `InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address` or `addr instanceof Inet4Address` (**API >= 23**) to filter **ip address** among them. Check below:

```
public static String getMobileIPAddress() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress() && 
                    addr instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    return  addr.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";
}
```

Comment: could you please share InetAddressUtils library gradle here!

Comment: For API >= 23 refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178289/1950812

Comment: Ow sorry, I forgot that it's deprecated use `addr instanceof Inet4Address` instead of that. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This code get WIFI IP address:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Comment: this return wifi ip address i was looking for mobile network address