# android get phone IP address

Tags: java, android, ip

I'm trying to get and then send IP address from android application.

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

this works if mobile is online from wifi connection. But if I'll turn on mobile data then this returns `0.0.0.0` as IP. How can I solve that?

Comment: @VivekMishra application won't work anyway if it's offline

Comment: It will only return ip in case you are connected to wifi

Comment: @VivekMishra there's not nothing similar for mobile data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IP address of the device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device)