# How to get IP address from mobile type network (no Wi-Fi)?

Tags: android, networking, android-networking, connectivity, lte

Is there a way to get the IP address of the device without using Wi-Fi?

I just find how to get IP from Wi-Fi connection:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
int ipAddress = connectionInfo.getIpAddress();
```

But now I'm searching how to get it without Wi-Fi. Just using the mobile type network.

Comment: By mobile type network do you mean telephony or GPRS?

Comment: Looks like this guy has the answer for ya! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device

Comment: @NickA i mean when you are connected to the network 3G