# How to run this project on Eclipse Mars?

Tags: android, eclipse

I imported an android project from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0z3LFuVZAYYQ214VVVtODh3OWM/view?usp=sharing), it says min SDK 10 and max SDK 19, so I downloaded the API versions from 10 to 19, also in layout -> main.xml -> in Android version to use for rendering layout I chose API 19.

When I am running this app on my phone (Note 2, Kitkat). I keep getting error that the application has been stopped. I have attached below the image of the screenshot of the logcat.

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0z3LFuVZAYYb3NueDlaT3JkblU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How do I ask a good question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hello,actually i am building an app where there will be live streaming and an ip address will be generated , using that ip address anyone can view the streaming within the same wifi .                                                                        I am done with the streaming part , but can u guide me how to generate ip address .

Comment: what do people keep posting screenshots of their errors? did you never heard of copy-pasting text?

Comment: sorry to bother u mate @njzk2 ..actually m new to stackoverflow.. wont repeat nxt tym.

Comment: @s.g: please fix it this time, the question may be useful to someone in the future, and we like to keep them readable here. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer : build-> clean and run , it worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the 3rd red line of the shared image

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.foxdogstudios.peepers.PeeperspAplication:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.foxdogstudios.peepers.PeepersApplication" on path
> /data/app-lib/com.foxdogstudios.peepers-1.apk, /vendor/lib /system/lib
> ```

It seems that the built apk does not include the class `PeepersApplication`

Comment: thanks.... but the prb is fixed now, the app is running... i want to generate ip address for the live streaming part..can u help me how to do it ?

Comment: Device on which android application is installed and device used to view live video stream   are connected to same local network.

Comment: @swaty ips are usually assigned to the device as soon as they get connected to a network - see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device