# How can I identify my Android application has been connected to a specific IP addres?

Tags: android, adb, internet-connection

I have an Android application which will connect to a specific IP address and port number. I use a LG device for testing my application and I have connected my device to the internet.

My question: How can I identify that my application has been connected to my target IP address and port number? Is there any command in adb which can show me my application's connections to an IP address on the device?

I am using `adb shell netcfg`, but I can not find anything about my application connection to my target IP! Is `adb shell netcfg` command is a suitable command for this purpose or there is a problem about my application and it has not been connected to my target IP address at all? In addition, when I want to use this command in Sumsung S6, I got this `error:/system/bin/sh: netcfg: not found`. So I think this command is not a perfect solution.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code

Comment: which ip address u are talking, device ip you can find out from device info.
Are u talking about application connection to server ip?

Comment: I am talking about a server ip address.

Comment: @sasikumar I mean the ip address of a server, not IP address of my device.