# How can I be connected with both data and wifi network at the same time in android

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, mobile-data

I have looked all the similar question related to this in SO . But couldn't find a solution and in most of the case the conclusion is "not possible" . But I have found an app named [speedify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedify.speedifyandroid) , by using that app I am able to be connected with both wifi and data network at the same time .

**Why do I need this ?**

In my app, I am connected with a camera via wifi, I am fetching data from that camera and I need to send those data to server . While I am connected to that camera , I can't connect to any other network (WIFI or data connection) but by using the mentioned app, I can connect to both WIFI(which is used to connect with camera) and data network at the same time and I can fetch data from camera and send it to server.

I don't want any dependency in my app . How can I overcome this issue ?

Any help will be highly appreciated .

Comment: This is accomplished by first establishing a connection to a Speed Server in the cloud. The Speedify client software then works in tandem with the Speed Server to intelligently divide traffic and deliver the combined speed of all your available Internet connections.

Comment: Your comment does not answer the question

Comment: source how speedify app works : http://channelbonding.net/

Answer (score 2):

Find all IP addresses of your phone. See [How to get IP address of the device from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code)

Use the wifi IP address to communicate with the camera. Use the other IP address to communicate with the internet via GSM.

To specify the local address use `Socket()` with the extra arguments:

```
Socket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
```

or

```
Socket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , I will try and let you know .

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate ?

Comment: What part don't you understand? Use different local addresses (=interfaces) for the different connections.