# Android app is crashing on not finding URL

Tags: java, android, resttemplate

In my android activity I am using AsyncTask to get data from server using **restTemplate** and it is working perfectly. I am testing it in my mobile with wifi  in my intranet environment as the server is for internal users and I am able to get data from server. But the problem is as sudden I turn Off wifi or change the network, the app crashes **(Connection timed out)**. I know that the URL my app is trying to fetch data is no more accessible from internet but how to **prevent app crash** or show some notification something like no network. My code is

```
 private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


            String username = "user";
            String password = "pass";
            String getAllItems = "http://172.16.243.15:8080/myapp/restGetAllItem";



            HttpAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(username, password);
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
            requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

            final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

            try{
                ResponseEntity<List> responseEntity=restTemplate.exchange(getAllItems, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), List.class);
                server_response=responseEntity.getBody();
                System.out.println("server response size is"+server_response.size());
            } catch (HttpClientErrorException e){

            }



            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v){


            ProgressBar progressBar=(ProgressBar)getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(getView().GONE);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getContext(), server_response);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

    }
```

Comment: share your crash log with question

Comment: Need to check if a network connection is available first, then make the connection. Still may have an issue if the connection drops out. Need to see crash log as something else might be happening.

Comment: share your log cat

Comment: You should use a better networking library than AsyncTask if you want HTTP connections to be retried. AsyncTask isn't required to perform HTTP, only to get networking off the main thread.

Comment: @Tigger: How to check network connection. I tried ConnectivityManager and NetworkInfo but still app crashing. Reason may be network is connected to the internet but how to check to a specific URL whether reachable or not

Comment: @cricket_007 actually in my case retried will not help as it would not be able to get connected with internet to my intranet server ever.

Comment: Well, still. The Volley library exposes a literal `onError` response back on the UI thread.

Comment: @ashok : OK, as the server is on a private network you could check the IP of the device, if in a valid range for the private network, connect otherwise alert message. See: [How to get IP address of the device from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code)

Comment: @cricket_007 I have not used Volley so far. Can you help me how to make same request and get response from server using Volley. Is it an alternative of restTemplate?.

Comment: RestTemplate is a spring class. Unless you are using Spring-Android / Spring Boot, then I would avoid compile anything Spring related to reduce app size. The documentation is fine https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You also need to handle multiple exceptions such as this for different reasons, You only catched the CLienErrorException

also add something like this to handle exception

```
try{
//Your Connection Code

} catch (HttpClientErrorException e){
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Client Error", e);
  // Do something else, if wanted.

}
catch (InterruptedIOException iioe)
{
   // Exception thrown when network timeout occurs
   System.err.println ("Remote host timed out during read operation");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connection Error", e);
  // Do something else, if wanted.
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  //Do Something
}
finally
{
  //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When an exception occurs due to network error, the value of `server_response` will not be set resulting it to be null.

You may use `<String, String, Boolean>` as type of your `AsyncTask` and return false inside the catch block so that inside the `onPostExecute` method you can check the boolean result whether the result was obtained or not. If the result is false, you can show an error toast and return.

Alternatively, you can also check for null condition for the value `server_response` before using it inside the `onPostExecute` method.