# Android app that adds a device properties and then can share this config file to other user

Tags: android, sockets, iot

Here is my problem, I've done an app to configure an IoT home device and saves this device properties on a simple SharedPreferences file, that's already done, but the other goal is to give this app the capability of "Invite" another user using this app so that this user can control this ALREADY configured device...I'm having trouble finding the specific name of this "Feature",

At this moment I've been thinking of simply adding the capabily of Sharing this file to the other app, like "Share my Devices", and pair the phones so that the other receives the file with the already configured devices. But I imagine more appropriate the scenario of "Invite User" to control the devices, and when doing it, the app receives a notification for accepting, but...what must happen after this on the underground?, I'm I little confused for "What to search", to start doing this, for example, when I didn't knew what was the concept of refreshing a webpage in real time I got the keyword for "polling", and just with that I was able to do the work, So, I don't know If you could just give a direction of what to search for the feature I'm looking, or at leats example of tecnologies using something close to this.

Comment: There are other ways you can get the ip address: you don't need to use an API for that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6064510/1333975