# Android code to display carrier-assigned IP address

Tags: android

I am relatively new to Android/Java programming, but I am trying get up to speed  to develop a new application for work.

I am looking for insight on developing an Android snippet that will show me the same IP addresses listed in the Settings menu, with a single click.  I have worked through the code provided at [How to get IP address of the device from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code), but this code is not providing the same IP address found in settings.

Comment: Can you show us what is the difference between the addresses it is listing and which ones are shown in settings?

Comment: Sure, the application is generating output of "fe80::eca5:eff:feec:1cba%dummy0", where my settings shows the IPs of 100.70.247.184 and 2600:100e:b112:249a:4cbe:f0dd:4ceb:55fa.

Side note: I believe that "dummy0" is the interface being referenced by the original code.  I had thought about trying to search by interface name to get the IP, but I'm not sure what the interface name would be.

Comment: The question you link to has several answers which return different IP addresses based on how they get it. A device can have multiple addresses some even unknown to it.

Comment: Yeah, that's another reason why I wondered if there was a way to grab just the mobile carrier provided IP based on the interface name.  Is there a standard for that in Android? Or is there a better way to go about doing it when I am only looking for the IP provided by the carrier?

Comment: I've been able to modify one of the code snippets from the link in my original post to get IPv4 working, but IPv6 is still not providing the right address.