# Access the IP Address of mobile

Tags: security, google-play, ip, app-store, mobile-application

I am developing an application using flutter. Actually, I want to read the IP address of the device but I have doubt about Google and App Store policy about reading IP address. 
**Please guide me should I read the IP address or not.**

Comment: why do you need the ip address?

Comment: I want to use this for multiple purposes like from country/city users are sending the most request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just read the IP address of the device on the server instead? Then you won't fall foul on any privacy protection.

Comment: what if someone uses the proxy?

Comment: Then maybe you respect their privacy wishes and use the proxy address?

Answer (score 0):

If you get permissions like:

```
// AndroidManifest.xml permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And equivalen on iOS, you should not have legal problems with Apple or Google, it is assumed that you may use that information.

Answer (score 0):

If the user allows your application to use internet and to access the network state you should not have any problem *Google and App Store policy* since the user give you the authorisation to use that information.

You can find more about how to find the IP address from this topic [How to get IP address of the device from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code)