# How to get IP address by mobile number?

Tags: python, terminal, command, ip-address, phone-number

I was working with IP, mobile numbers and whatsapp-web to trace location using python. I'm trying to find someone's IP address by their mobile number.

I have got some answers but they all are for android.

I have read https://www.techjunkie.com/track-location-someone-whatsapp/. From this I have tried through command `netstat` but not able to get my answer.

Is there any way to find an IP address by the mobile number from the terminal or having any code in python to find the IP address by mobile number?

Comment: "Mobile" == "Cell phone" or similar device.

Answer (score 0):

First, a single sim card can have different number so to track the IP you would need the sim ID that's unique for a sim card and IP is assigned for that unique sim ID.

Second, you are not assigned the same IP each time you are connected to the internet. Telecom providers don't have enough IP to assign one to each individual so they maintain a pool of free IP from which they assign one when you connect to the internet.

So there's no way you could track someone's IP with their phone numbet.

Comment: can we use [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code) for getting desire output?

Answer (score -1):

yehh, great question ever...
but if calling via internet or using omegle then their are more possibilities to get ip and track the user or someone's location without knowing himself....

Yes,  it is possible. there is extension called 'Omegle IP protector'.  You have to add this extension over your computer or laptop then you can track easily.
For further information check on the Google.