# How can I get IP address in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to get smartphone's IP address by using socket class but my code dosent work.

```
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {

             Socket mysocket = null;
              try {
                 Socket mysocket = new Socket("www.google.com", 80);
                 String Addr = mysocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
                 tv8.setText(Addr);
             }catch (Exception e){
                 tv8.setText("error");
             }
         }
     });
```

Is the code has anything wrong? it works in my phone but doesnt show IP address so I cant know what the problem is.

Comment: Is an exception thrown?  What is the message?  If not, have you checked if `mysocket` is connected with `mysocket.isConnected()` before querying the address?

Comment: When I added 
Log.e("ERR", e.getMesseage());
in code, the app turned off and I cant see any log about that

Comment: This might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.