# How to use NetworkUtils class on Android

Tags: android

I would like to use the android.net.NetworkUtils class, to obtain a list of dns servers. How do i use this class on android.

Comment: possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070144/how-do-you-get-the-current-dns-servers-for-android

Comment: According to [_this answer_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16435288/1364368) the class `NetworkUtils` is not part of the public API.